# Анимация появления карты с прорисовкой границ и с последующей закраской внутри

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, анимация

У меня есть файлы в форматах *.jpg, *.svg  стран мира.
Например Канады:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать плавную анимацию появления карты с прорисовкой границ и с последующей закраской внутри?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Пример с использованием** [Vivus.js](https://maxwellito.github.io/vivus/):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var states = [
      "#DE-BW",
      "#DE-BY",
      "#DE-BE",
      "#DE-BB",
      "#DE-HB",
      "#DE-HH",
      "#DE-HE",
      "#DE-MV",
      "#DE-NI",
      "#DE-NW",
      "#DE-RP",
      "#DE-SL",
      "#DE-SN",
      "#DE-ST",
      "#DE-SH",
      "#DE-TH"
    ],
    colors = [
      "#a3bc8f",
      "#8fbc8f",
      "#a3d58f",
      "#a3d5a5",
      "#84d5a5",
      "#6dd5b8",
      "#6dd5b8",
      "#6db4c4",
      "#81b4c4",
      "#a3bc8f",
      "#8fbc8f",
      "#a3d58f",
      "#a3d5a5",
      "#84d5a5",
      "#84d5a5",
      "#a3d58f"
    ];

  function fillMap(state, color, time) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(state).css("fill", color);
    }, time);
  }

  new Vivus("germany", {
    duration: 500
  }, function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
      fillMap(states[i], colors[i], (i + 1) * 225);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
path {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 0.8;
  transition: fill 1.6s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vivus@latest/dist/vivus.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="175" height="175" viewBox="0 0 800 800" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
    <g id="germany">
      <path id="DE-BW" d="M180.99,750.43l0.58,2.09l-3.47,0.13L180.99,750.43zM206.4,570.93l8.66,-0.33l4.12,-7.25l6.54,0.95l0.83,-6.5l-2.07,-1.9l-1.84,2.62l0.97,-2.42l-4.96,-0.95l1.24,-2.93l11.93,-2.03l3.81,4.36l0.36,-3.78l5.23,-0.86l-1.54,8.57l1.8,1.69l3.63,-3.95l1.67,3.87l3.98,-4.23l4.61,11.83l-3.88,5.45l3.04,0.98l3.58,-3.6l0.77,9.54l5.81,-0.09l2.95,-6.01l3.68,3.64l-1.77,6.05l4.31,5.07l-3.48,1.64l3.18,9.66l-2.99,2.1l0.91,5.72l7.87,4.93l-2.46,4.64l2.62,0.9l-0.01,5l6.23,1.2l6.94,10.77l-2.17,1.09l1.94,4.53l-2.36,10.79l4.98,5.72l-5.35,2.5l1.74,-3.05l-1.91,-0.44l-3.02,4.26l-5.88,-4.76l-0.89,3.63l4.3,5.42l-0.75,8.22l-4.84,1.1l-4.09,5.13l-4.1,-1.88l-4.39,1.77l-4.24,7.74l6.02,9.22l4.53,16.17l-3.72,23.3l3.8,5.37l-4.73,2.12l3.47,2.57l0.82,7.82l-3.45,3.6l-3.16,-4.43l-3.99,3.28l-7.15,-2.49l-6.35,6.24l-7.29,0.87l-2.47,5.16l0,0l-32.49,-12.44l-12.39,2.97l-5.46,-8.47l-2.45,1.83l1.4,4.16l-4.17,-1.79l-0.25,-6.73l-1.86,0.82l-2.53,-4.15l-1.61,3.9l-0.73,-3.78l-3.23,-0.87l0.58,2.52l-5.88,1.11l-4.98,9.09l4.45,3.28l8.21,-3.17l1.48,2.35l-3.33,4.98l-3.59,-3.6l-4,2.98l1.93,2.27l-6.63,1.06l-11.33,-5.16l-7.36,5.95l-9.36,1.3l-3.24,-4.09l-4.44,-0.06l-8.25,5.23l-3.72,-2.72l3.29,-0.43l0.41,-3.27l-6.5,1.03l-5.01,-10.15l2.32,-3.43l0.55,-13.76l4.19,-8.82l-3.37,-5.92l0.47,-8.22l7.41,-17.3l3.29,-2.43l-0.78,-6.43l6.8,-23.67l8.46,-11.19l7.49,-4.36l9.11,-15.81l0,0l8.06,-13.06l2.02,-13.01l6.23,-5.87l-2.43,-2.9l3.64,-10.75l-4.12,-1.49l-1.29,-13.08l0,0l3.37,0.03l5.46,6.77l3.5,-2.61l-1.32,-6.75l6.19,-1.33l0.61,8.58l7.72,1.09l0.59,3.21l4.26,-1.08l-1.4,3.51l-3.26,-0.13l-1.54,5.66l3.08,1.47l6.37,-5.89l0.1,-4.73l11.14,-1.27l-3.41,-4.71L206.4,570.93z"
      />
      <path id="DE-BY" d="M266.23,478L270.48,473.26L272.67,475.36L276.56,474.22L278.37,478.53L284.63,480.24L288.76,490.22L292.4,489.44L294.9,494.07L298.27,493.2L301.79,496.22L302.29,506.5L309.26,509.04L310.2,504.4L317.53,505.09L317.46,502.02L309.21,497.5L309.05,495L316.62,490.37L323.22,490.38L326.34,494.82L334.65,492.94L337.36,496.54L336.61,501L343.32,502.7L345.43,493.56L343.09,481.72L345.84,482.04L349.35,477.53L354.77,478.48L354.1,485.17L355.54,487.62L358.09,486.59L360.59,492.12L376.99,487.67L379.89,490.67L386.17,487.29L386.17,487.29L389.97,490.78L389.6,494.54L397.47,497.79L397.47,497.79L399.97,502L396.88,504.61L404.79,512.65L403.76,518.53L408.57,521.79L407.68,523.58L422.28,531.21L421.51,535.67L425.94,537.18L421.17,550.4L416.77,554.73L424.29,560.24L424.69,566.94L426.76,566.79L428.63,574.79L432.09,576.2L432.93,584.92L439.31,588.8L440.77,593.47L451.2,593.76L456.61,597.66L466.17,613.93L473.22,615.73L479.86,622.03L480.49,628.52L486.35,632.92L488.68,629.75L494.89,632.16L497.58,638.83L501.81,638.26L508.3,649.33L505.41,654.76L508.14,656.38L507.23,664.48L501.4,674.04L487.21,666.82L482.75,669.85L482.75,682.09L476.08,692.11L456.13,698.62L439.37,711.16L439.64,716.26L446.79,726.7L450.85,728.57L455.02,737.46L448.93,749.36L455.88,749.36L459.93,752.81L457.76,771.19L454.98,773.84L441.86,765.17L440.83,762.75L443.63,759.83L439.46,756.18L440.97,754.08L429.62,754.15L427.77,757.93L422.77,758.66L419.03,752.07L407.26,753.58L407.05,747.56L401.39,751.59L403.92,760.43L391.59,758.63L381.14,762.7L367.89,761.51L363.8,768.98L354.89,769.14L351.75,772.99L354.14,775.6L348.77,775.17L344.36,780.07L341.52,780.26L343.37,777.17L340.34,776.63L334.6,780.14L325.74,779.97L323.1,772.23L318.88,772.09L321.96,769.19L320.06,766.94L313.1,769.09L301.71,763.96L300.04,767.25L296.94,767.13L292.61,765.2L294.23,762.41L291.51,762.49L293.9,776.69L291.37,781.53L284.63,788.67L274.79,792L278.68,781.46L275.23,780.46L269.83,784L269.5,774.78L263.57,772L261.64,766.05L255.45,767.74L251.7,765.87L250.8,761.43L246.66,767.24L237.99,765.89L237.99,765.89L240.46,760.72L247.75,759.86L254.1,753.61L261.25,756.1L265.24,752.82L268.4,757.25L271.85,753.65L271.03,745.83L267.56,743.26L272.29,741.14L268.49,735.77L272.21,712.47L267.69,696.3L261.67,687.07L265.91,679.33L270.3,677.56L274.4,679.44L278.49,674.31L283.33,673.21L284.08,664.99L279.78,659.56L280.66,655.93L286.54,660.69L289.56,656.42L291.47,656.87L289.73,659.92L295.08,657.42L290.1,651.69L292.46,640.9L290.51,636.37L292.69,635.28L285.74,624.51L279.51,623.31L279.52,618.31L276.9,617.41L279.36,612.77L271.48,607.84L270.57,602.12L273.56,600.01L270.38,590.36L273.86,588.72L269.55,583.64L271.32,577.6L267.63,573.96L264.68,579.97L258.88,580.05L258.1,570.52L254.53,574.11L251.49,573.13L255.37,567.68L250.76,555.86L246.78,560.08L245.11,556.21L241.49,560.16L239.69,558.47L241.23,549.9L236,550.76L235.63,554.54L231.83,550.18L219.9,552.21L218.66,555.14L223.62,556.09L222.65,558.51L224.49,555.9L226.55,557.79L225.72,564.3L219.18,563.34L215.05,570.59L206.4,570.93L206.4,570.93L204.1,566.8L209.25,554.87L206.67,553.11L208.4,550.81L205.58,549.91L205.3,544.47L202.13,544.72L200.98,531.51L202.97,529.97L201.66,525.34L198.33,524.58L199.68,520.26L207.43,516.82L209.49,520.27L213.92,514.58L223.4,516.33L227.46,520.98L232.45,519.97L231.68,505.4L242.14,506.21L241.49,502.46L247.38,498.61L248.36,487.1L257.28,489.23L264.73,482.94z"
      />
      <path id="DE-BE" d="M485.13,257.7L485.2,257.74L485.2,257.74L488.12,260.2L487.19,265.7L496.58,272.25L493.65,278.32L503.07,281.3L496.02,292.2L495.77,288.21L485.31,286.24L484.46,283.74L481.5,284.77L481.48,288.32L473.68,284.09L462.87,286.78L460.54,284.53L465.46,274.35L462.28,273.56L463.02,266.3L468.62,266.16L468.88,261.95L471.62,262.01L472.85,258.49L477.73,262.39L484.8,259.5L484.07,257.58L484.07,257.58L484.98,257.05L484.98,257.05L485.36,257.16L485.36,257.16z"
      />
      <path id="DE-BB" d="M344.3,209.85l8.02,1.19l1.8,-3.16l7.08,1.66l1.2,-8.96l7.4,-3.75l4.06,2.84l5.54,-0.75l-1.38,-3.02l4.06,0.48l10.37,-5.54l1.53,-7.65l7.88,3.47l3.88,-2.05l1.78,3.73l8.55,2.52l3.33,5.44l13.8,-0.45l1.43,2.9l4.58,0.3l0.85,3.82l12.47,-1.39l-1.35,2.75l3.96,0.87l9.22,-8.82l5.16,3.63l4.42,-6.82l6.74,3.41l1.96,-5.34l3.03,0.62l2.39,-2.91l1.82,-8.42l4.82,-1.24l5.59,-7.61l6.29,-0.43l-2.43,-3.12l1.17,-4.79l5.37,5.8l2.49,8.85l20.64,-0.67l-0.89,7.39L524.76,195l10.43,0.28l3.57,-5.47l6.01,-2.08l0,0l2.24,7.22l-4.5,6.74l-0.82,12.83l-13.97,12.39l1.04,8.08l-2.41,4.88l14.57,9.2l18.26,18.7l-2.18,4.03l1.88,4.48l-6.32,9.97l3.71,12.6l7.73,3.9l-2.04,12.46l4.91,5.25l-4.07,16.95l-6.63,7.67l10.62,17.16l-1.73,7.98l0,0l-2.12,-1.61l-1.12,4.56l-4.09,0.3l-3.03,-3.09l-11.42,3.93l-3.51,3.93l-12.47,-4.08l-3.16,6.77l-3.47,0.11l1.82,3.13l-4.07,7.31l-2.52,-2.38l-11.84,3.46l-14.67,-0.7l-9.17,-8.53l-1.34,2.87l-3.49,-1.17l-3.59,5.3l-3.34,-1.15l-2.51,-3.24l2.05,-9.8l-4.06,-4.59l1.12,-2.54l-6.89,-5.4l0,0l8.48,-7.22l-2.99,-16.74l-6.2,0.89l0.25,-2.97l-4.62,0.05l-0.97,-3.69h-6.75l-0.47,-3.38l-4.14,0.53l-6.92,-5.08l-3.75,3.09l-4.62,-0.36l-3.86,-4.92l-2.84,1.76l-13.81,-15.78l5.04,-6.12l-3.3,-2.48l3.94,-9.8l-2.16,-7.13l3.66,-6.58l-5.64,-4.62l-3.65,2.66l0.29,-3.85l-2.94,0.24l1.64,-9.97l3.81,-0.42l-1.96,-9.34l3.75,-9.1l-1.54,-5.94l-2.51,-1.75l-4.4,2.67l-0.12,-4.27l-9.2,1.93l-9.36,-3.58l0.63,-4.53l-6.5,-3.88l-3.03,1.23l-1.1,-3.25l-3.23,-0.37l0.88,-2.82l-2.52,0.24l0,0l-9.3,-4.54l-7.29,2.44L344.3,209.85zM484.8,259.5l-7.07,2.89l-4.88,-3.9l-1.23,3.52l-2.74,-0.06l-0.25,4.21l-5.6,0.15l-0.75,7.26l3.18,0.78l-4.92,10.19l2.33,2.25l10.8,-2.69l7.8,4.23l0.02,-3.55l2.96,-1.03l0.85,2.5l10.45,1.97l0.25,3.99l7.05,-10.9l-9.42,-2.97l2.93,-6.08l-9.39,-6.55l0.93,-5.5l-2.92,-2.46l0,0l0.17,-0.58l0,0l-0.38,-0.1l0,0l-0.91,0.52L484.8,259.5z"
      />
      <path id="DE-HB" d="M167.33,198.78l0.72,-0.1l0,0l6.18,1.69l-1.23,2.18l2.79,2.05l13.14,0.83l2.17,3.48l5.17,-2.19l2.46,2.73l-2.24,1.09l2.65,2.01l-0.55,5.41l-2.93,3.42l-4.4,-2.78l-2.81,2.1l-3.19,-3.5l-3.43,1.47l-6.32,-13.54l-6.92,-3.24l0,0l0,0l0,0l-1.31,-3.24l0,0L167.33,198.78zM169.27,158.35l8.9,-0.44l-2.71,3.76l0.96,8.47l-3.74,1l-1.17,-3.99l0,0l1.42,-1.84L169.27,158.35z"
      />
      <path id="DE-HH" d="M246.33,163.56L248.94,155.53L253.09,160.38L257.57,153.33L262.18,153.98L263.46,150.25L267.7,150.59L268.7,146.04L274.31,144.08L275.84,145.66L272.71,150.58L277.67,155.3L276.21,160.45L273.15,161.8L273.86,167.23L277,167.42L284.34,175.11L283.21,176.76L283.21,176.76L278.78,180.74L274.68,180.74L266.87,173.56L262.59,178.61L258.16,178.86L257.4,174.35L254.73,177.15L251.25,173.6L249.16,163.92z"
      />
      <path id="DE-HE" d="M228.57,363.63L239.71,364.71L243.77,370.74L239.94,370.01L241.01,373.34L238.39,372.36L237.13,376.89L240.77,381.62L240.85,386.94L236.65,388.67L236.04,392.66L233.68,392.15L235.59,394.41L246.59,399.46L249.05,395.24L246.92,396.99L244.56,392.48L250.72,390.28L250.53,387.99L254.96,391.71L254.04,387.33L257.29,387.02L258.96,391.32L258.96,391.32L261.78,400.55L267.08,401.15L267.92,406.43L278.65,410.58L276.22,417.97L274.12,413.9L271.17,415.3L274.68,417.62L272.55,423.36L276.66,425.82L276.6,428.59L266.07,428.06L264.81,431.25L267.6,434.96L260.4,435.21L262.79,436.27L261.76,438.66L264.33,437.27L267.42,441.23L265.3,446.07L260.55,447.42L255.68,465.57L261,466.66L260.6,462.87L267,462.49L268.82,467.35L265.93,468.54L266.23,478L266.23,478L264.73,482.94L257.28,489.23L248.36,487.1L247.38,498.61L241.49,502.46L242.14,506.21L231.68,505.4L232.45,519.97L227.46,520.98L223.4,516.33L213.92,514.58L209.49,520.27L207.43,516.82L199.68,520.26L198.33,524.58L201.66,525.34L202.97,529.97L200.98,531.51L202.13,544.72L205.3,544.47L205.58,549.91L208.4,550.81L206.67,553.11L209.25,554.87L204.1,566.8L206.4,570.93L206.4,570.93L204.44,572.16L207.85,576.87L196.72,578.15L196.62,582.87L190.25,588.76L187.17,587.29L188.71,581.63L191.97,581.76L193.37,578.24L189.11,579.32L188.52,576.11L180.8,575.02L180.19,566.45L174,567.78L175.32,574.53L171.82,577.14L166.36,570.37L162.99,570.34L162.99,570.34L158.96,559.7L166.61,552.81L163.07,552.18L160.28,546.83L156.62,531.69L147.81,525.89L128.79,532.15L121.66,523.67L125.77,521.07L126.65,516.79L131.62,519.2L131.78,515.09L128.71,512.68L130.36,509.21L135.33,505.79L138.18,507.96L138.42,502.49L142.89,503.54L143.7,499.7L139.92,492.22L133.79,488.56L136.77,484.32L135.78,477.16L138.86,473.89L142.66,476.29L144.72,474.55L144.01,461.08L144.01,461.08L146.74,456.2L144.6,450.64L153.07,441.46L158.94,443.44L165.39,437.61L165.28,432.87L170.31,427.46L168.09,421.33L181.98,418.31L180.44,415.53L184.98,408.27L182.08,401.69L174.03,404.39L171.58,401.32L175.59,395.35L180.31,391.22L195.87,389.93L196.45,386.03L192.88,380.49L201,376.79L205.64,379.11L205.92,384.27L213.6,382.79L223.52,369.32L221.31,366.92z"
      />
      <path id="DE-MV" d="M506.34,97.76l4.16,7.29l9.15,5.19l13.36,13.4l-2.67,1.61l1.77,4.97l-11.17,-0.75l-6.21,3.27l-0.74,-3.29l-1.09,3.36l-5.44,-0.79l7.1,-6.32l-1.86,-8.65l3.52,0.01l-0.37,5.89l1.59,-2.95l3.65,2.11l0.45,-4.57l-4.91,-8.62l-3.86,0.08l1.03,5.1l-0.28,-2.04l-3.95,3.73l-0.23,-5.16l-5.59,3.1l2.7,-9.62l-4.04,-5.48L506.34,97.76zM435.9,69.27l1.61,1.44l-3.42,-0.11L435.9,69.27zM424.89,63.46l2.05,3.08l22.51,0.9l0.62,1.97l-7.87,2.04l-10.53,-1.85l-6.48,6.64l10.89,-5.09l-1.95,4.42l1.53,-3.05l2.24,3.08l3.26,-2.78l1.61,5.67l7.15,-7.56l6.79,-2.47l-0.25,4.24l4.26,3.17l0.76,9.39l4.76,1.33L464,88.41l2.73,-1.42l6.5,3.42l2.33,5.54l2.84,0.23l-3.42,2.36l6.37,-1.55l-2.24,3.23l1.8,-1.25l3.69,7.51l2.08,0.08l-0.64,-4.17l14.05,-4.86l-0.8,2.15l6.6,5.51l-3.72,7.61l10.86,11.49l-5.72,4.9l-0.46,3.65l18.19,11.06l10.48,-0.91l-3.31,4.93l4.15,1.7l8.41,38.14l0,0l-6.01,2.08l-3.57,5.47L524.76,195l8.17,-10.36l0.89,-7.39l-20.64,0.67l-2.49,-8.85l-5.37,-5.8l-1.17,4.79l2.43,3.12l-6.29,0.43l-5.59,7.61l-4.82,1.24l-1.82,8.42l-2.39,2.91l-3.03,-0.62l-1.96,5.34l-6.74,-3.41l-4.42,6.82l-5.16,-3.63l-9.22,8.82l-3.96,-0.87l1.35,-2.75l-12.47,1.39l-0.85,-3.82l-4.58,-0.3l-1.43,-2.9l-13.8,0.45l-3.33,-5.44l-8.55,-2.52l-1.78,-3.73l-3.88,2.05l-7.88,-3.47l-1.53,7.65l-10.37,5.54l-4.06,-0.48l1.38,3.02l-5.54,0.75l-4.06,-2.84l-7.4,3.75l-1.2,8.96l-7.08,-1.66l-1.8,3.16l-8.02,-1.19l0,0l-5.31,-1.53l0.82,-4.63l-6.83,-3.55l-6.5,-12.73l-4.42,-1.59l-5.27,4.67l-8.65,-7.03l-6.65,0.68l0,0l2.42,-9.56l12.25,-6.35l-0.17,-6.55l5.62,0.36l2.65,-8.29l-1.86,-5.47l-4.63,-0.29l-5.85,-5.36l0.85,-13.02l6.93,-5.62l1.96,2.87l3.45,-1.03l-4.59,-1.62l0.66,-3.64l0,0l8.62,-5.35l8.99,-0.97l5.08,3.39l-0.13,5.23l4.98,-2.57l7.9,6.75l1.52,-7.62l-2.42,0.9l-0.06,-4.29L354.8,120l-2.75,-0.41l-0.14,-3.94l6.66,-2.2l-0.02,5.96l1.88,-6.97l3.46,-0.25l3.28,-6.13l-1.35,-1.37l-4.67,5.94l-0.27,-2.75l9.71,-8.54l10.65,0.8l17.71,-4.2l3.87,-5.85l9.57,-6.35L424.89,63.46zM464.13,50.28l-5.16,15.79l2.21,-14.48L464.13,50.28zM482.31,41.36l-3.58,5.45l2.77,6.09l13.64,-0.74l2.81,2.3l-6.61,12.74l2.47,4.76l3.76,0.38l5.99,6.49l-3.54,7.89l-0.54,-3l-3.58,-0.14l3.71,-3.18l-5.99,1.1l4.77,-3.81l-4.41,2.36L492,77.51l-5.2,1.21l-9.55,7.89l0.34,2.53l0.46,-1.89l3.38,1.09l-1.64,3.56l-6.46,-3.18l1.98,0.57l0.78,-3.61l-4.17,2.7l-4.35,-1.79l-0.39,-2.88l-3.42,1.6l2.85,-2l-4.49,-3.49l0.83,-4.21l8.47,-1.45l-3.12,-4.98l-3.91,0.79l1.8,-3.63l-3.64,0.9l3.07,-4.87l3.67,0.83l-1.8,4.08l4.56,-3.56l-2.7,-0.61l0.18,-2.75l-3.88,0.31L464,56.46l6.37,-0.96l3.81,4.46l-0.45,-4.24l3.66,-2.99l-1.02,3.48l2.34,-1.22l2.35,7.22l2.45,2.46l3.33,-1.08l0.54,-9.21l-4.2,1.51l-4.83,-6.9l-8.04,6.07l2.62,-9.48l-7.86,9.54l5.41,-10.88L482.31,41.36z"
      />
      <path id="DE-NI" d="M60.4,159.06l-6.04,1.6l1.74,3.04l-5.74,-3.15l6.06,-3.78L60.4,159.06zM97.87,144.43l2.35,1.9l-4.99,-0.89L97.87,144.43zM109.16,141.9l3.35,1.47l-10.55,2.34l0.91,-3.27L109.16,141.9zM118.39,139.44l6,1.1l-9.43,1.86L118.39,139.44zM129.41,138.01l4.77,2.17l-7.91,-1.23L129.41,138.01zM179.97,127.51l5.23,5.99l7.84,1.37l8.04,-1.86l-1.01,-3.55l0,0l13.06,-0.56l6.67,2.83l12.21,17.13l2.84,8.25l11.48,6.46l0,0l2.83,0.35l2.08,9.69l3.48,3.54l2.68,-2.8l0.75,4.5l4.44,-0.25l4.28,-5.05l7.81,7.18h4.1l4.43,-3.98l0,0l18.28,7.39l0,0l6.65,-0.68l8.65,7.03l5.27,-4.67l4.42,1.59l6.5,12.73l6.83,3.55l-0.82,4.63l5.31,1.53l0,0l4.55,7.01l7.29,-2.44l9.3,4.54l0,0l-2.7,3.89l-2.98,-0.7l-0.45,6.88l-12.05,6.6l-19.61,-3.49l-4.16,6.16l-11.02,1.12l1.98,13.53l1.93,-0.26l5.79,11.2l3.61,-1.46l-2.47,5.88l4.52,7.55l-4.03,0.18l-0.71,3.44l8.97,8.94l-5.84,3.47l6.5,11.69l-4.59,3.15l2.97,2.63l-0.96,4.01l-6.47,3.21l1.43,4.79l-16.92,0.71l-8.8,4.69l5.67,4.84l-2.42,1.99l2.34,4.9l-4.6,4.32l-0.2,3.87l8.03,17.4l0,0l-3.96,2.24l1.14,6.25l-3.23,-2.15l-5.53,2.62l-5.49,-3.91l-4.01,0.48l-4.54,9.57l-4.16,2.37l-2,-1.58l-3.07,5.57l-5.45,1.37l-1.4,-1.95l-7.55,6.33l0,0l-1.67,-4.3l-3.25,0.31l0.92,4.38l-4.44,-3.72l0.19,2.28l-6.15,2.2l2.35,4.52l2.14,-1.75l-2.47,4.21l-11,-5.05l-1.91,-2.26l2.36,0.51l0.61,-3.99l4.2,-1.72l-0.08,-5.32l-3.63,-4.73l1.26,-4.53l2.61,0.98l-1.06,-3.33l3.82,0.73l-4.05,-6.03l-11.14,-1.08l0,0l-4.86,-0.35l0.01,-9.56l4.54,-5.24l0.89,-6.85l-8.64,0.73l1.04,-5.53l-4.3,-2.48l0.06,-4.22l-4.21,1.27l-2.11,-2.07l1.21,-9.22l-3.83,-2.61l1.27,-3.61l-9.09,-0.57l-1.66,-6.2l3.7,1.13l-0.5,-4.2l2.61,-0.77l-7.08,-5.01l10.03,-12.94l-1.83,-4.11l2.7,-3.43l-2.38,-2.18l-3,-0.29l-7.38,10.27l-5.19,1.29l-9.48,-0.64l-0.33,-11.32l-3.23,-2.83l-6.02,3.41l-3.47,-1.36l-5.41,7.04l-7.26,-1.47l0.85,5.74l8.13,4.31l-0.09,15.3l4.74,3.12l-7.04,7.64l-7.68,-2.54l-5.97,6.44l-10.21,0.4l-3.27,3.45l-6.11,-4.99l7.84,-3.25l1.17,-4.9l-7.94,-4.33l3.57,-6.49l-1.59,-3.61l3.82,-0.74l-3.51,-5.79l-14.26,-3.71l-1.57,-5.4l-5.14,-2.29l-2.74,4.46l2.44,1.08l-1.28,4.74l-18.29,11.56l-14.88,2.32l0,0l-2.39,-5.02l3.02,-8.69l-5.28,-9.79l-3.12,3.39l-11.76,-2.84l-3.81,-2.53l-1.13,-6.92l5.53,-1.08l-3.48,-6.68l2.53,-2.25l19.34,0.57l2.08,-21.73l8.28,-16.56l-2.42,-13.97l3.04,-4.26l-1.13,-6.84l2.29,-8.14l4.02,-0.19l-18.76,-2.27l1.21,-20.46l4.21,3.68l-3.7,-3.96l4.04,2.69l2.51,-3.23l-3.45,-3.97l9.89,-9.75l7.43,-1.81l10.45,1.73l11.38,-5.21l0.02,2.11l6.55,-1.16l1.8,-2.54l-1.58,2.92l13.81,-0.12l1.09,7.07l4.65,0.61l3.51,10.82l-7.1,3.26l0.18,3.1l8.78,7.68l4.21,-0.14l2.93,-5.51l-0.19,-6.81l-5.28,0.11l3.42,-9.74l3.58,-0.12l8.07,6.35l3.47,-0.63l2.41,3.76l0,0l1.17,3.99l3.74,-1l-0.96,-8.47l2.71,-3.76l-8.9,0.44l0,0l-2.48,-9.53l4.18,-12.99l4.08,-7.1L179.97,127.51zM167.27,198.66L167.27,198.66l1.31,3.24l6.92,3.24l6.32,13.54l3.43,-1.47l3.19,3.5l2.81,-2.1l4.4,2.78l2.93,-3.42l0.55,-5.41l-2.65,-2.01l2.24,-1.09l-2.46,-2.73l-5.17,2.19l-2.17,-3.48l-13.14,-0.83l-2.79,-2.05l1.23,-2.18l-6.18,-1.69L167.27,198.66z"
      />
      <path id="DE-NW" d="M76.38,302.23L91.26,299.91L109.56,288.35L110.84,283.61L108.4,282.53L111.14,278.07L116.27,280.36L117.84,285.76L132.1,289.47L135.61,295.25L131.79,295.99L133.38,299.6L129.81,306.09L137.75,310.42L136.58,315.32L128.74,318.57L134.84,323.57L138.11,320.12L148.32,319.71L154.29,313.27L161.97,315.81L169,308.17L164.26,305.05L164.35,289.75L156.22,285.44L155.37,279.7L162.63,281.17L168.04,274.14L171.52,275.49L177.54,272.09L180.77,274.92L181.1,286.24L190.58,286.88L195.77,285.58L203.15,275.32L206.15,275.61L208.53,277.79L205.83,281.23L207.66,285.33L197.63,298.27L204.71,303.28L202.09,304.04L202.59,308.25L198.89,307.12L200.54,313.31L209.63,313.88L208.36,317.5L212.19,320.1L210.98,329.32L213.09,331.4L217.31,330.13L217.25,334.35L221.55,336.83L220.51,342.36L229.15,341.63L228.26,348.48L223.71,353.72L223.71,363.28L228.57,363.63L228.57,363.63L221.31,366.92L223.52,369.32L213.6,382.79L205.92,384.27L205.64,379.11L201,376.79L192.88,380.49L196.45,386.03L195.87,389.93L180.31,391.22L175.59,395.35L171.58,401.32L174.03,404.39L182.08,401.69L184.98,408.27L180.44,415.53L181.98,418.31L168.09,421.33L170.31,427.46L165.28,432.87L165.39,437.61L158.94,443.44L153.07,441.46L144.6,450.64L146.74,456.2L144.01,461.08L144.01,461.08L138.65,459.88L134.03,452.04L134.05,444.96L125.1,441.26L126.51,436.67L122.85,435.21L119.22,437.66L120.94,445.04L114.44,447.46L115.13,451.42L110.08,455.63L96.22,457.75L93.72,465.7L85.91,467.3L85.17,464.78L81.7,469.61L79.69,468.42L78.04,471.05L75.88,469.03L72.18,473.18L67.87,473.6L67.91,476.25L64.81,476.88L65.96,482.74L63.25,484.33L59.61,480.43L56.06,482.31L59.52,493.57L53.31,496L51.25,492.58L49.29,495.2L46.99,490.88L37.45,495.98L34.92,490.75L34.4,497.38L34.4,497.38L30.39,491.64L32.63,486.02L31,480.75L23.07,480.09L20.03,475.41L25.8,466.98L19.96,466.99L16.38,457.62L11.14,457.68L10.3,452.21L6.95,449.92L10.22,448.04L9.84,444.94L13.35,444.87L14.68,437.33L9.87,436.02L10.22,431.03L2.1,431.94L0.03,424.56L3.1,422.7L6,425.79L9.29,420.15L19.74,413.5L17.53,411.91L19.17,409.75L13.86,412L13.18,404.88L23.01,392.69L22.22,377.36L14.41,367.78L16.02,362.62L10.66,360.78L11.4,356.38L5.75,354.14L8.02,349.6L5.13,345.39L12.71,341.21L19.2,343.66L16.2,337.39L34.27,345.09L33.62,340.22L38.56,342.38L52.24,335.8L55.28,337.7L61.53,328.65L52.4,323.19L52.83,319.98L55.56,319.49L57.1,315L63.11,314.79L71.34,303.9z"
      />
      <path id="DE-RP" d="M34.4,497.38L34.92,490.75L37.45,495.98L46.99,490.88L49.29,495.2L51.25,492.58L53.31,496L59.52,493.57L56.06,482.31L59.61,480.43L63.25,484.33L65.96,482.74L64.81,476.88L67.91,476.25L67.87,473.6L72.18,473.18L75.88,469.03L78.04,471.05L79.69,468.42L81.7,469.61L85.17,464.78L85.91,467.3L93.72,465.7L96.22,457.75L110.08,455.63L115.13,451.42L114.44,447.46L120.94,445.04L119.22,437.66L122.85,435.21L126.51,436.67L125.1,441.26L134.05,444.96L134.03,452.04L138.65,459.88L144.01,461.08L144.01,461.08L144.72,474.55L142.66,476.29L138.86,473.89L135.78,477.16L136.77,484.32L133.79,488.56L139.92,492.22L143.7,499.7L142.89,503.54L138.42,502.49L138.18,507.96L135.33,505.79L130.36,509.21L128.71,512.68L131.78,515.09L131.62,519.2L126.65,516.79L125.77,521.07L121.66,523.67L128.79,532.15L147.81,525.89L156.62,531.69L160.28,546.83L163.07,552.18L166.61,552.81L158.96,559.7L162.99,570.34L162.99,570.34L164.27,583.42L168.4,584.91L164.76,595.65L167.19,598.55L160.95,604.42L158.93,617.43L150.88,630.49L150.88,630.49L131.83,621.58L127.53,623.95L122.93,620.83L115.24,622.89L105.97,617.8L103.79,610.87L100.07,611.29L100.53,609.42L95.44,611.9L95.44,611.9L90.8,604.11L96.92,598.67L97.9,591.28L90.86,589.38L88.35,585.05L91.78,580.99L89.4,570.28L86,572.11L74.13,564.82L68.56,565.32L47.32,576.71L32.78,573.51L32.78,573.51L31.36,571.48L36.01,561.98L41.52,556.64L42.26,548.11L36.02,548.01L31.65,544.07L29.14,545.3L23.49,539.27L22.8,534.31L19.88,533.95L15.67,523.45L17.64,512.64L20.8,511.23L19.88,506.01L26.47,502.86L28.42,497.6L31.65,499.21z"
      />
      <path id="DE-SL" d="M32.78,573.51L47.32,576.71L68.56,565.32L74.13,564.82L86,572.11L89.4,570.28L91.78,580.99L88.35,585.05L90.86,589.38L97.9,591.28L96.92,598.67L90.8,604.11L95.44,611.9L95.44,611.9L91.03,616.11L82.31,615.57L78.54,612.15L75.84,616.27L74.48,608.71L67.6,605.53L62.02,606.55L61.86,612.35L55.69,611.27L51.29,600.01L44.72,593.48L46.87,591.65L42.98,588.08L43.77,585.86L35.9,580.85L31.98,581.4z"
      />
      <path id="DE-SN" d="M409.06,420.36L403.51,415.05L403.77,405.34L400.41,396.85L403.55,395.99L400.5,382.43L404.19,379.5L405.85,372.11L418.09,370.21L419.2,367.43L421.97,368.9L430.88,365.69L429.82,367.29L435.07,361.75L440.17,363.52L444.84,359.68L451.1,364.45L453.48,361.28L458.17,363.61L458.17,363.61L465.06,369.01L463.95,371.54L468.01,376.13L465.95,385.93L468.46,389.17L471.8,390.33L475.4,385.03L478.89,386.2L480.23,383.33L489.4,391.86L504.07,392.57L515.91,389.1L518.43,391.49L522.5,384.18L520.68,381.05L524.16,380.93L527.32,374.16L539.79,378.24L543.3,374.3L554.72,370.38L557.76,373.47L561.84,373.17L562.96,368.61L565.08,370.21L565.08,370.21L565.46,375.9L579.17,381.68L580.87,394.65L584.98,401.69L580.86,421.64L569.28,447.49L558.02,443.73L559.96,436.33L554.58,437.64L556.68,430.81L550.29,427.18L550.48,424.72L549.9,427.06L544.64,427.52L537.82,423.85L535.1,430.7L539.27,430.96L538.35,434L543.85,435.87L543.2,439.71L535.53,440.02L523.44,448.37L512.17,450.25L512.04,455.14L509.38,456.85L488.35,459.06L488.24,465.7L484.54,469.3L478.5,464.63L475.36,471.66L470.54,470.42L467.23,479.28L456.82,478.64L456.11,484.77L451.41,489.31L443.25,483.66L442.67,486.5L441.71,484.71L437.9,486.39L436.06,489.9L433.92,487.95L423.7,489.94L412.12,505.41L412.5,512.26L409.51,511.86L409.75,507.48L406.3,504.99L407.28,502.51L403.83,502.33L402.79,497.38L397.47,497.79L397.47,497.79L389.6,494.54L389.97,490.78L386.17,487.29L386.17,487.29L384.37,484.79L387.82,484.27L388.86,480.96L382.78,475.87L391.14,466.23L394.64,474.55L396.15,472.01L401.44,471.96L400.58,466.68L403.18,468.31L403.78,465.78L407.84,466.63L411.24,463.28L407.72,460.17L407.97,455.85L405.43,455.76L409.46,451.27L407,447.48L413.15,447.22L414.87,444.14L419.12,445.23L421.83,440.04L432.72,437.54L429.76,429.79L423.35,427.71L423.1,423.08L412.5,419.03z"
      />
      <path id="DE-ST" d="M365.45,218.95L367.97,218.71L367.09,221.53L370.32,221.9L371.42,225.16L374.45,223.93L380.95,227.81L380.32,232.33L389.68,235.92L398.88,233.99L399,238.25L403.4,235.59L405.91,237.34L407.45,243.27L403.7,252.38L405.66,261.72L401.86,262.14L400.21,272.11L403.15,271.87L402.87,275.71L406.51,273.05L412.15,277.67L408.49,284.25L410.65,291.37L406.71,301.18L410.01,303.66L404.97,309.78L418.78,325.56L421.61,323.81L425.47,328.72L430.09,329.08L433.84,326L440.76,331.08L444.91,330.55L445.38,333.93L452.13,333.93L453.1,337.62L457.72,337.57L457.46,340.54L463.67,339.65L466.65,356.39L458.17,363.61L458.17,363.61L453.48,361.28L451.1,364.45L444.84,359.68L440.17,363.52L435.07,361.75L429.82,367.29L430.88,365.69L421.97,368.9L419.2,367.43L418.09,370.21L405.85,372.11L404.19,379.5L400.5,382.43L403.55,395.99L400.41,396.85L403.77,405.34L403.51,415.05L409.06,420.36L409.06,420.36L406.94,425.62L409.56,427.41L404.76,435.61L402.78,431.91L392.16,432.77L384.1,423.91L375.7,425.21L369.96,418.22L358.26,419.09L357.31,409.95L350.71,407.1L357.69,399.43L352.63,390.75L347.7,387.76L326.79,386.99L323.84,374.77L320.02,370.61L320.54,368.2L322.79,369.28L322.26,366.55L308.21,364.11L308.21,364.11L300.18,346.71L300.39,342.85L304.98,338.52L302.64,333.62L305.06,331.63L299.4,326.79L308.2,322.1L325.12,321.39L323.69,316.6L330.16,313.39L331.12,309.38L328.15,306.74L332.74,303.59L326.25,291.89L332.08,288.43L323.11,279.48L323.82,276.04L327.85,275.86L323.33,268.31L325.79,262.43L322.18,263.89L316.39,252.69L314.46,252.95L312.48,239.42L323.5,238.31L327.66,232.14L347.27,235.63L359.32,229.03L359.76,222.15L362.75,222.84z"
      />
      <path id="DE-SH" d="M166.82,66.59l2.35,2.45l-1.94,1.67l-2.67,-4.29L166.82,66.59zM332.49,58.08l9.41,2.94l5.37,11.14l-7.81,-2.19l-4.48,2.14l-2.14,-4.95l-4.11,0.5l1.58,1.6l-2.51,-1.5l1.31,-7.3L332.49,58.08zM167.37,57.79l-0.91,4.28l-1.17,-5.25L167.37,57.79zM180.99,55.13l-0.17,6.25l-5.39,1.13L173.59,58L180.99,55.13zM171.44,52.84l1.27,2.23l-4.19,-2.04L171.44,52.84zM160.46,46.18l0.94,2.71l-2.42,0.45l-4.45,-6.2l4.47,-5.15l-1.37,2.73L160.46,46.18zM169.54,33.33l3.91,1.16l-1.25,7.3l-10.71,-2.42l1.81,-5.03L169.54,33.33zM163.97,0.73l1.77,0.6l-4.43,0.14l2.81,3.28l-5.56,5.21l1.11,7.58l3.58,2.32l11.07,-1.05l2.19,-2.65l19.86,0.96l18.37,5.74l0.89,4.46l2.86,0.97l3.16,0.14l4.19,-4.6l1.73,5.88l11.27,-9.7l-0.47,5.07l12.03,3.77l3.84,4.81l3.35,-1.14l-0.01,-3.72l3.27,1.96l5.13,10.28l-2.49,-0.09l2.35,1.88l-0.49,13.02l-4,5.24L253,64.29l2.07,2.87l16.57,-4.02l4.75,3.21l-4.27,15.75l3.28,-1.77l2.68,-9.43l6.21,-2.37l17.55,7.84l6.6,6.44l5.49,-0.85l8.99,-7.58l6.01,1.51l5.56,-3.27l0.84,2.82l-4.37,2.11l2.28,16.93l-14.19,12.24l-3.89,-2.32l-3.69,6.28l2.12,5.41l5.44,0.71l2.12,3.81l0,0l-0.66,3.64l4.59,1.62l-3.45,1.03l-1.96,-2.87l-6.93,5.62l-0.85,13.02l5.85,5.36l4.63,0.29l1.86,5.47l-2.65,8.29l-5.62,-0.36l0.17,6.55l-12.25,6.35l-2.42,9.56l0,0l-18.28,-7.39l0,0l1.13,-1.65l-7.34,-7.69l-3.15,-0.18l-0.71,-5.44l3.07,-1.35l1.46,-5.15l-4.96,-4.72l3.12,-4.92l-1.53,-1.58l-5.61,1.96l-1,4.55l-4.24,-0.34l-1.27,3.73l-4.62,-0.65l-4.48,7.05l-4.14,-4.86l-2.61,8.04l0,0l-11.48,-6.46l-2.84,-8.25l-12.21,-17.13l-6.67,-2.83l-13.06,0.56l0,0l-6.27,-6.5l-1.5,-7.38l-4.91,-2.29l4.75,-2.33l5.01,1.18l1.7,-2.38l-3.64,-7.99l-4.47,1.29l-3.12,-5.67l1.94,-12.13l-8.27,-0.65l-2.03,2.44L173,82.47l1.71,-5.06l2.16,1.62l3.1,-1.96l-5.35,-1.38l0.8,-2.11l16.15,-2.02l11.39,-7.45l-3.03,-0.39l-1.19,-4.4l-5.54,6.62l-5.8,-1.17l5.53,-13.43l-0.83,-1.84l-4.22,1.34l2.68,-2.28l-10.42,-11.71l-5.97,-17.46L162.4,23.4l-4.71,-3.58l-3.78,14.22l1.04,-17.71l6.25,-15.67L163.97,0.73z"
      />
      <path id="DE-TH" d="M308.21,364.11L322.26,366.55L322.79,369.28L320.54,368.2L320.02,370.61L323.84,374.77L326.79,386.99L347.7,387.76L352.63,390.75L357.69,399.43L350.71,407.1L357.31,409.95L358.26,419.09L369.96,418.22L375.7,425.21L384.1,423.91L392.16,432.77L402.78,431.91L404.76,435.61L409.56,427.41L406.94,425.62L409.06,420.36L409.06,420.36L412.5,419.03L423.1,423.08L423.35,427.71L429.76,429.79L432.72,437.54L421.83,440.04L419.12,445.23L414.87,444.14L413.15,447.22L407,447.48L409.46,451.27L405.43,455.76L407.97,455.85L407.72,460.17L411.24,463.28L407.84,466.63L403.78,465.78L403.18,468.31L400.58,466.68L401.44,471.96L396.15,472.01L394.64,474.55L391.14,466.23L382.78,475.87L388.86,480.96L387.82,484.27L384.37,484.79L386.17,487.29L386.17,487.29L379.89,490.67L376.99,487.67L360.59,492.12L358.09,486.59L355.54,487.62L354.1,485.17L354.77,478.48L349.35,477.53L345.84,482.04L343.09,481.72L345.43,493.56L343.32,502.7L336.61,501L337.36,496.54L334.65,492.94L326.34,494.82L323.22,490.38L316.62,490.37L309.05,495L309.21,497.5L317.46,502.02L317.53,505.09L310.2,504.4L309.26,509.04L302.29,506.5L301.79,496.22L298.27,493.2L294.9,494.07L292.4,489.44L288.76,490.22L284.63,480.24L278.37,478.53L276.56,474.22L272.67,475.36L270.48,473.26L266.23,478L266.23,478L265.93,468.54L268.82,467.35L267,462.49L260.6,462.87L261,466.66L255.68,465.57L260.55,447.42L265.3,446.07L267.42,441.23L264.33,437.27L261.76,438.66L262.79,436.27L260.4,435.21L267.6,434.96L264.81,431.25L266.07,428.06L276.6,428.59L276.66,425.82L272.55,423.36L274.68,417.62L271.17,415.3L274.12,413.9L276.22,417.97L278.65,410.58L267.92,406.43L267.08,401.15L261.78,400.55L258.96,391.32L258.96,391.32L266.51,385L267.91,386.94L273.36,385.58L276.44,380.01L278.43,381.59L282.59,379.22L287.13,369.65L291.14,369.17L296.62,373.08L302.16,370.46L305.39,372.61L304.25,366.35z"
      />
    </g>
  </svg>
```

Comment: Без комментариев....)))

Answer (score 12):

Если есть файл svg, то анимацию прорисовки границ можно сделать с помощью изменения атрибута `stroke-dashoffset` от максимального значения равного длине линии до нуля.

Длину линии можно узнать при помощи функции `getTotalLength()`

*Пример скрипта*

```
<script>
    function TotalLength(){
      var path = document.querySelector('#check');
      var len = Math.round(path.getTotalLength() );
      alert("Длина пути - " + len);
    };
</script>
```

*Пример вычисления длины линии смотри ниже.*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
 
 <input  type="button" value="Total"  onclick="TotalLength()"/>
<div>   
<svg 
     width="370" height="460" viewBox="0 0 370 460" > 
 
         <path id="check" fill= "none" stroke ="grey" stroke-width ="0.5" 
         
   d="M198.93,96.23l-0.22,-5.9l3.63,0.58l1.63,0.96l3.35,4.92l-0.76,4.97l-4.15,2.77l-2.28,-3.12L198.93,96.23zM212.14,108.88l0.33,-1.49l-1.97,-2.45l-5.65,-0.19l0.75,3.68l5.25,0.83L212.14,108.88zM248.49,155.83l3.08,5.1l0.81,0.57l3.07,-1.27l3.02,0.2l2.98,0.28l-0.25,-2.64l-4.84,-5.38l-6.42,-1.08l-1.35,0.67L248.49,155.83zM183.06,93.13l-2.71,4.19l6.24,0.52l4.61,4.44l4.58,1.5l-1.09,-5.68l-2.14,-6.73l-7.58,-5.35l-5.5,-2.04l0.2,5.69L183.06,93.13zM208.96,82.89l5.13,-0.12l-2.22,4l-0.04,5.3l3.01,5.76l5.81,1.77l4.96,-0.99l5.18,-10.73l3.85,-4.45l-3.38,-4.97l-2.21,-10.65l-4.6,-3.19l-4.72,-3.68l-3.58,-9.56l-6.52,0.94l1.23,4.15l-2.87,1.25l-1.94,5.32l-1.94,7.46l1.78,7.26L208.96,82.89zM145.21,136.27l3.92,1.95l12.67,-1.3l-5.82,4.77l0.36,3.43l4.26,-0.24l7.07,-4.58l9.5,-1.67l1.71,-5.22l-0.49,-5.57l-2.94,-0.5l-2.5,1.93l-1.1,-4.13l-0.95,-5.7l-2.9,-1.42l-2.57,4.41l4.01,11.05l-4.9,-0.85l-4.98,-6.79l-7.89,-4l-2.64,3.32L145.21,136.27zM167.77,94.21l-3.65,-2.9l-1.5,-0.66l-2.88,4.28l-0.05,2l4.66,0.01L167.77,94.21zM166.31,106.56l0.93,-3.99l-3.95,-2.12l-4.09,1.39l-2.27,4.26l4.16,4.21L166.31,106.56zM195.4,139.8l4.62,-1.11l1.28,-8.25l-0.09,-5.95l-2.14,-5.56l-0.22,1.6l-3.94,-0.7l-4.22,4.09l-3.02,-0.37l0.18,8.92l4.6,-0.87l-0.06,6.47L195.4,139.8zM192.12,185.41l-5.06,-3.93l-4.71,-4.21l-0.87,-6.18l-1.76,-8.92l-3.14,-3.84l-2.79,-1.55l-2.47,1.42l1.99,9.59l-1.41,3.73l-2.29,-8.98l-2.56,-3.11l-3.17,4.81l-3.9,-4.76l-6.24,2.87l1.4,-4.46l-2.87,-1.87l-7.51,5.84l-1.95,3.71l-2.35,6.77l4.9,2.32l4.33,-0.12l-6.5,3.46l1.48,3.13l3.98,0.17l5.99,-0.67l5.42,1.96l-3.66,1.44l-3.95,-0.37l-4.33,1.41l-1.87,0.87l3.45,6.35l2.49,-0.88l3.83,2.15l1.52,3.65l4.99,-0.73l7.1,-1.16l5.26,-2.65l3.26,-0.48l4.82,2.12l5.07,1.22l0.94,-2.86l-1.79,-3.05l4.6,-0.64L192.12,185.41zM199.86,184.43l-1.96,3.54l-2.47,2.49l3.83,3.54l2.28,-0.85l3.78,2.36l1.74,-2.73l-1.71,-3.03l-0.84,-1.53l-1.68,-1.46L199.86,184.43zM182.25,154.98l-2.13,-2.17l-3.76,0.4l-0.95,1.38l4.37,6.75L182.25,154.98zM210.94,168.15l3.01,-6.93l3.34,-1.85l4.19,-8.74l-5.36,-2.47l-5.84,-0.36l-2.78,2.77l-1.47,4.23l-0.04,4.82l1.75,8.19L210.94,168.15zM228.09,145.15l5.76,-0.18l8.04,-1.61l3.59,1.28l4.18,-2.26l1.75,-2.84l-0.63,-4.52l-3,-4.23l-4.56,-0.8l-5.71,0.97l-4.46,2.44l-4.09,-0.94l-3.78,-0.5l-1.78,-2.7l-3.22,-2.61l0.64,-4.43l-2.42,-3.98l-5.52,0.03l-3.11,-3.99l-5.78,-0.8l-1.06,5.1l3.25,3.74l5.8,1.45l2.81,5.09l0.34,5.6l0.97,5.99l7.45,3.42L228.09,145.15zM139.07,126.88l5.21,-5.05l2.62,-0.59l2.16,-4.23l0.38,-9.77l-3.85,1.91l-4.3,-0.18l-5.76,8.19l-4.76,8.98l3.8,2.51L139.07,126.88zM211.25,143.05l1.53,-4.14l-1.02,-3.46l-2.45,-3.92l-4.03,3.02l-1.49,4.92l3.4,2.79L211.25,143.05zM202.94,154.49l-0.73,-2.88l-5,1.26l-3.34,-2.11l-3.32,4.8l3.09,6.28l-5.72,-1.17l-0.06,3.01l6.97,7.05l1.94,3.38l2.7,0.73l4.6,-3.41l0.5,-8.21l-4.24,-4.07L202.94,154.49zM128.95,308.23l-1.16,-2.34l-2.8,-1.77l-1.39,-2.05l-0.95,-1.5l-2.64,-0.46l-1.72,-0.67l-2.94,-0.96l-0.24,1.02l1.08,2.38l2.89,0.78l0.5,1.23l2.51,1.5l0.84,1.51l4.6,1.92L128.95,308.23zM250.65,230.6l-2,-2.11l-2.06,0.5l-0.25,-3.06l-3.21,-2.04l-3.07,-2.27l-1.63,-1.75l-1.43,1.03l-0.52,-2.96l-2.03,-0.55l-0.96,6.13l-0.36,5.11l-2.44,3.14l3.8,-0.6l0.96,3.65l3.99,-3.23l2.78,-3.38l1.57,2.86l4.36,1.51L250.65,230.6zM130.12,178.05l7.38,-4.18V170l3.48,-6.41l6.88,-6.69l3.52,-2.47l-3.01,-4.2l-2.72,-2.95l-7.16,-0.57l-4,-2.16l-9.48,1.63l2.74,6.23l-2.43,6.43l-1.94,6.87l-1.2,3.86l6.47,4.69L130.12,178.05zM264.36,205.36l0.32,-1.01l-0.03,-3.17l-2.19,-2.08l-2.57,1.05l-1.19,4.17l0.7,3.56l3.14,-0.36L264.36,205.36zM288.18,212.9l4.41,6.6l3.45,2.85l4.92,-7.87l0.87,-4.93l-4.41,-0.47l-4.03,-6.7l-4.45,-1.64l-6.6,-4.97l5.15,-3.63l-2.65,-7.54l-2.44,-3.35l-6.77,-3.35l-2.92,-5.55l-5.21,1.99l-0.36,-3.86l-3.86,-4.32l-6.22,-4.71l-2.65,3.71l-5.55,2.66l0.42,-6.06l-4.81,-10.05l-7.11,4.06l-2.59,7.7l-2.21,-5.92l2.06,-6.37l-7.24,2.65l-2.88,3.99l-2.15,8.42l0.89,9.05l3.98,0.04l-2.93,3.92l2.33,2.96l4.55,1.25l5.93,2.42l10.2,1.82l5.08,-1.04l1.5,-2.42l2.21,2.79l2.47,0.46l2.97,4.96l-1.8,1.98l5.68,2.63l4.29,3.68l1.08,2.55l0.77,3.24l-3.63,6.93l-0.98,3.44l0.94,2.42l-5.77,0.86l-5.27,0.12l-1.85,4.87l2.37,2.23l8.11,-1.03l-0.04,-1.89l4.08,3.15l4.18,3.28l-0.98,1.77l3.4,3.02l6.02,3.53l7.6,2.39l-0.46,-2.09l-2.92,-3.67l-3.96,-5.37l7.03,5l3.54,1.66l0.97,-4.44l-1.82,-6.3l-1.16,-1.73l-3.81,-3.03l-2.95,-3.91l0.35,-3.94L288.18,212.9zM222.35,51.34l2.34,7.29l4.96,5.88l9.81,-1.09l6.31,1.97l-4.38,6.05l-2.21,-1.78l-7.66,-0.71l1.19,8.31l3.96,6.04l-0.8,5.2l-4.97,3.46l-2.27,5.47l4.55,2.65l3.82,8.55l-7.5,-5.7l-1.71,0.94l1.38,9.38l-5.18,2.83l0.35,5.85l5.3,0.63l4.17,1.44l8.24,-1.84l7.33,3.27l7.49,-7.19l-0.06,-3.02l-4.79,0.48l-0.39,-2.84l3.92,-3.83l1.33,-5.15l4.33,-3.83l2.66,-4.76l-2.32,-7.1l1.94,-2.65l-3.86,-1.89l8.49,-1.63l1.79,-3.15l5.78,-2.6l4.8,-13.47l4.57,-4.94l6.62,-11.12l-6.1,0.1l2.54,-4.3l6.78,-3.99l6.84,-8.9l0.12,-5.73l-5.13,-6.04l-6.02,-2.93l-7.49,-1.82l-6.07,-1.49l-6.07,-1.5l-8.1,3.98l-1.49,-2.53l-8.57,0.98l-5.03,2.57l-3.7,3.65l-2.13,11.74L239,24.52l-3.48,-1.14l-4.12,7.97l-5.5,3.35l-3.27,0.66l-4.17,3.84l0.61,6.65L222.35,51.34zM296.75,316.34l-0.98,-1.98l-1.06,1.26l0.7,1.36l3.56,1.71l1.04,-0.26l1.38,-1.66l-2.6,0.11L296.75,316.34zM239.75,238.48l0.61,1.63l1.98,0.14l3.28,-3.34l0.06,-1.19l-3.85,-0.06L239.75,238.48zM301.88,304.92l-2.87,-1.8l-3.69,-1.09l-0.97,0.37l2.61,2.04l3.63,1.34l1.36,-0.08L301.88,304.92zM326.76,309.71l-0.36,-2.24l-1.96,0.72l0.87,-3.11l-2.8,-1.32l-1.29,1.05l-2.49,-1.18l0.98,-1.51l-1.88,-0.93l-1.83,1.47l1.86,-3.82l1.5,-2.8l0.54,-1.22l-1.3,-0.2l-2.43,1.55l-1.74,2.53l-2.9,6.92l-2.35,2.56l1.22,1.14l-1.75,1.47l0.43,1.23l5.44,0.13l3.01,-0.25l2.69,1.01l-1.98,1.93l1.67,0.14l3.25,-3.58l0.78,0.53l-0.61,3.37l1.84,0.77l1.27,-0.15l1.18,-3.61L326.76,309.71zM305.57,314.47l-2.81,4.56l-4.63,0.58l-3.64,-2.01l-0.92,-3.07l-0.89,-4.46l2.65,-2.83l-2.48,-2.09l-4.19,0.43l-5.88,3.53l-4.5,5.45l-2.38,0.67l3.23,-3.8l4.04,-5.57l3.57,-1.9l2.35,-3.11l2.9,-0.3l4.21,0.03l6,0.92l4.74,-0.71l3.53,-3.62l4.62,-1.59l2.01,-1.58l2.04,-1.71l-0.2,-5.19l-1.13,-1.77l-2.18,-0.63l-1.11,-4.05l-1.8,-1.55l-4.47,-1.26l-2.52,-2.82l-3.73,-2.83l1.13,-3.2l-3.1,-6.26l-3.65,-6.89l-2.18,-4.98l-1.86,2.61l-2.68,6.05l-4.06,2.97l-2.03,-3.16l-2.56,-0.85l-0.93,-6.99l0.08,-4.8l-5,-0.44l-0.85,-2.27l-3.45,-3.44l-2.61,-2.04l-2.32,1.58l-2.88,-0.58l-4.81,-1.65l-1.95,1.4l0.94,9.18l1.22,5.12l-3.31,5.75l3.41,4.02l1.9,4.44l0.23,3.42l-1.55,3.5l-3.18,3.46l-4.49,2.28l1.98,2.53l1.46,7.4l-1.52,4.68l-2.16,1.46l-4.17,-4.28l-2.03,-5.17l-0.87,-4.76l0.46,-4.19l-3.05,-0.47l-4.63,-0.28l-2.97,-2.08l-3.51,-1.37l-2.01,-2.38l-2.8,-1.94l-5.21,-2.23l-3.92,1.02l-1.31,-3.95l-1.26,-4.99l-4.12,-0.9l0.15,-6.41l1.09,-4.48l3.04,-6.6l3.43,-4.9l3.26,-0.77l0.19,-4.05l2.21,-2.68l4.01,-0.42l3.25,-4.39l0.82,-2.9l2.7,-5.73l0.84,-3.5l2.9,2.11l3.9,-1.08l5.49,-4.96l0.36,-3.54l-1.98,-3.98l2.09,-4.06l-0.17,-3.87l-3.76,-3.95l-4.14,-1.19l-3.98,-0.62l-0.15,8.71l-2.04,6.56l-2.93,5.3l-2.71,-4.95l0.84,-5.61l-3.35,-5.02l-3.75,6.09l0.01,-7.99l-5.21,-1.63l2.49,-4.01l-3.81,-9.59l-2.84,-3.91l-3.7,-1.44l-3.32,6.43l-0.22,9.34l3.27,3.29l3,4.91l-1.27,7.71l-2.26,-0.2l-1.78,5.88l0.02,-7l-4.34,-2.58l-2.49,1.33l0.32,4.67l-4.09,-0.18l-4.35,1.17l-4.95,-3.35l-3.13,0.6l-2.82,-4.11l-2.26,-1.84l-2.24,0.77l-3.41,0.35l-1.81,2.61l2.86,3.19l-3.05,3.72l-2.99,-4.42l-2.39,1.3l-7.57,0.87l-5.07,-1.59l3.94,-3.74l-3.78,-3.9l-2.75,0.5l-3.86,-1.32l-6.56,-2.89l-4.29,-3.37l-3.4,-0.47l-1.06,2.36l-3.44,1.31l-0.38,-6.15l-3.73,5.5l-4.74,-7.32l-1.94,-0.89l-0.63,3.91l-2.09,1.9l-1.93,-3.39l-4.59,2.05l-4.2,3.55l-4.17,-0.98l-3.4,2.5l-2.46,3.28l-2.92,-0.72l-4.41,-3.8l-5.23,-1.94l-0.02,27.65l-0.01,35.43l2.76,0.17l2.73,1.56l1.96,2.44l2.49,3.6l2.73,-3.05l2.81,-1.79l1.49,2.85l1.89,2.23l2.57,2.42l1.75,3.79l2.87,5.88l4.77,3.2l0.08,3.12l-1.56,2.35l0.06,2.48l3.39,3.45l0.49,3.76l3.59,1.96l-0.4,2.79l1.56,3.96l5.08,1.82l2,1.89l5.43,4.23l0.38,0.01h7.96h8.32h2.76h8.55h8.27h8.41l8.42,0l9.53,0l9.59,0l5.8,0l0.01,-1.64l0.95,-0.02l0.5,2.35l0.87,0.72l1.96,0.26l2.86,0.67l2.72,1.3l2.27,-0.55l3.45,1.09l1.14,-1.66l1.59,-0.66l0.62,-1.03l0.63,-0.55l2.61,0.86l1.93,0.1l0.67,0.57l0.94,2.38l3.15,0.63l-0.49,1.18l1.11,1.21l-0.48,1.56l1.18,0.51l-0.59,1.37l0.75,0.13l0.53,-0.6l0.55,0.9l2.1,0.5l2.13,0.04l2.27,0.41l2.51,0.78l0.91,1.26l1.82,3.04l-0.9,1.3l-2.28,-0.54l-1.42,-2.44l0.36,2.49l-1.34,2.17l0.15,1.84l-0.23,1.07l-1.81,1.27l-1.32,2.09l-0.62,1.32l1.54,0.24l2.08,-1.2l1.23,-1.06l0.83,-0.17l1.54,0.38l0.75,-0.59l1.37,-0.48l2.44,-0.47v0l0,0l-0.25,-1.15l-0.13,0.04l-0.86,0.2l-1.12,-0.36l0.84,-1.32l0.85,-0.46l1.98,-0.56l2.37,-0.53l1.24,0.73l0.78,-0.85l0.89,-0.54l0.6,0.29l0.03,0.06l2.87,-2.73l1.27,-0.73l4.26,-0.03l5.17,0l0.28,-0.98l0.9,-0.2l1.19,-0.62l1,-1.82l0.86,-3.15l2.14,-3.1l0.93,1.08l1.88,-0.7l1.25,1.19l0,5.52l1.83,2.25l3.12,-0.48l4.49,-0.13l-4.87,3.26l0.11,3.29l2.13,0.28l3.13,-2.79l2.78,-1.58l6.21,-2.35l3.47,-2.62l-1.81,-1.46L305.57,314.47zM251.91,243.37l1.1,-3.12l-0.71,-1.23l-1.15,-0.13l-1.08,1.8l-0.13,0.41l0.74,1.77L251.91,243.37zM109.25,279.8L109.25,279.8l1.56,-2.35L109.25,279.8zM105.85,283.09l-2.69,0.38l-1.32,-0.62l-0.17,1.52l0.52,2.07l1.42,1.46l1.04,2.13l1.69,2.1l1.12,0.01l-2.44,-3.7L105.85,283.09z" />
</svg> 
</div>
   <script>
         function TotalLength(){
          var path = document.querySelector('#check');
        var len = Math.round(path.getTotalLength() );
        alert("Длина пути - " + len);
        };
  </script>
</html>
```

Длина линии получилась:  `3635px`

Команда анимация прорисовки линии:

```
 <animate id="dash" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="30s" fill="freeze" values="3635;0"/>
```

Команда заполнения цветом:

```
<animate id="fillCanada" attributeName="fill" values="white;#AFCD72" begin="dash.end-17s" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
```

**Полный код анимации ниже:**

```html
<svg width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
<path id="CA" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-dasharray="3635" stroke-dashoffset="3635" title="Canada" stroke="grey" fill="none" class="land" d="M198.93,96.23l-0.22,-5.9l3.63,0.58l1.63,0.96l3.35,4.92l-0.76,4.97l-4.15,2.77l-2.28,-3.12L198.93,96.23zM212.14,108.88l0.33,-1.49l-1.97,-2.45l-5.65,-0.19l0.75,3.68l5.25,0.83L212.14,108.88zM248.49,155.83l3.08,5.1l0.81,0.57l3.07,-1.27l3.02,0.2l2.98,0.28l-0.25,-2.64l-4.84,-5.38l-6.42,-1.08l-1.35,0.67L248.49,155.83zM183.06,93.13l-2.71,4.19l6.24,0.52l4.61,4.44l4.58,1.5l-1.09,-5.68l-2.14,-6.73l-7.58,-5.35l-5.5,-2.04l0.2,5.69L183.06,93.13zM208.96,82.89l5.13,-0.12l-2.22,4l-0.04,5.3l3.01,5.76l5.81,1.77l4.96,-0.99l5.18,-10.73l3.85,-4.45l-3.38,-4.97l-2.21,-10.65l-4.6,-3.19l-4.72,-3.68l-3.58,-9.56l-6.52,0.94l1.23,4.15l-2.87,1.25l-1.94,5.32l-1.94,7.46l1.78,7.26L208.96,82.89zM145.21,136.27l3.92,1.95l12.67,-1.3l-5.82,4.77l0.36,3.43l4.26,-0.24l7.07,-4.58l9.5,-1.67l1.71,-5.22l-0.49,-5.57l-2.94,-0.5l-2.5,1.93l-1.1,-4.13l-0.95,-5.7l-2.9,-1.42l-2.57,4.41l4.01,11.05l-4.9,-0.85l-4.98,-6.79l-7.89,-4l-2.64,3.32L145.21,136.27zM167.77,94.21l-3.65,-2.9l-1.5,-0.66l-2.88,4.28l-0.05,2l4.66,0.01L167.77,94.21zM166.31,106.56l0.93,-3.99l-3.95,-2.12l-4.09,1.39l-2.27,4.26l4.16,4.21L166.31,106.56zM195.4,139.8l4.62,-1.11l1.28,-8.25l-0.09,-5.95l-2.14,-5.56l-0.22,1.6l-3.94,-0.7l-4.22,4.09l-3.02,-0.37l0.18,8.92l4.6,-0.87l-0.06,6.47L195.4,139.8zM192.12,185.41l-5.06,-3.93l-4.71,-4.21l-0.87,-6.18l-1.76,-8.92l-3.14,-3.84l-2.79,-1.55l-2.47,1.42l1.99,9.59l-1.41,3.73l-2.29,-8.98l-2.56,-3.11l-3.17,4.81l-3.9,-4.76l-6.24,2.87l1.4,-4.46l-2.87,-1.87l-7.51,5.84l-1.95,3.71l-2.35,6.77l4.9,2.32l4.33,-0.12l-6.5,3.46l1.48,3.13l3.98,0.17l5.99,-0.67l5.42,1.96l-3.66,1.44l-3.95,-0.37l-4.33,1.41l-1.87,0.87l3.45,6.35l2.49,-0.88l3.83,2.15l1.52,3.65l4.99,-0.73l7.1,-1.16l5.26,-2.65l3.26,-0.48l4.82,2.12l5.07,1.22l0.94,-2.86l-1.79,-3.05l4.6,-0.64L192.12,185.41zM199.86,184.43l-1.96,3.54l-2.47,2.49l3.83,3.54l2.28,-0.85l3.78,2.36l1.74,-2.73l-1.71,-3.03l-0.84,-1.53l-1.68,-1.46L199.86,184.43zM182.25,154.98l-2.13,-2.17l-3.76,0.4l-0.95,1.38l4.37,6.75L182.25,154.98zM210.94,168.15l3.01,-6.93l3.34,-1.85l4.19,-8.74l-5.36,-2.47l-5.84,-0.36l-2.78,2.77l-1.47,4.23l-0.04,4.82l1.75,8.19L210.94,168.15zM228.09,145.15l5.76,-0.18l8.04,-1.61l3.59,1.28l4.18,-2.26l1.75,-2.84l-0.63,-4.52l-3,-4.23l-4.56,-0.8l-5.71,0.97l-4.46,2.44l-4.09,-0.94l-3.78,-0.5l-1.78,-2.7l-3.22,-2.61l0.64,-4.43l-2.42,-3.98l-5.52,0.03l-3.11,-3.99l-5.78,-0.8l-1.06,5.1l3.25,3.74l5.8,1.45l2.81,5.09l0.34,5.6l0.97,5.99l7.45,3.42L228.09,145.15zM139.07,126.88l5.21,-5.05l2.62,-0.59l2.16,-4.23l0.38,-9.77l-3.85,1.91l-4.3,-0.18l-5.76,8.19l-4.76,8.98l3.8,2.51L139.07,126.88zM211.25,143.05l1.53,-4.14l-1.02,-3.46l-2.45,-3.92l-4.03,3.02l-1.49,4.92l3.4,2.79L211.25,143.05zM202.94,154.49l-0.73,-2.88l-5,1.26l-3.34,-2.11l-3.32,4.8l3.09,6.28l-5.72,-1.17l-0.06,3.01l6.97,7.05l1.94,3.38l2.7,0.73l4.6,-3.41l0.5,-8.21l-4.24,-4.07L202.94,154.49zM128.95,308.23l-1.16,-2.34l-2.8,-1.77l-1.39,-2.05l-0.95,-1.5l-2.64,-0.46l-1.72,-0.67l-2.94,-0.96l-0.24,1.02l1.08,2.38l2.89,0.78l0.5,1.23l2.51,1.5l0.84,1.51l4.6,1.92L128.95,308.23zM250.65,230.6l-2,-2.11l-2.06,0.5l-0.25,-3.06l-3.21,-2.04l-3.07,-2.27l-1.63,-1.75l-1.43,1.03l-0.52,-2.96l-2.03,-0.55l-0.96,6.13l-0.36,5.11l-2.44,3.14l3.8,-0.6l0.96,3.65l3.99,-3.23l2.78,-3.38l1.57,2.86l4.36,1.51L250.65,230.6zM130.12,178.05l7.38,-4.18V170l3.48,-6.41l6.88,-6.69l3.52,-2.47l-3.01,-4.2l-2.72,-2.95l-7.16,-0.57l-4,-2.16l-9.48,1.63l2.74,6.23l-2.43,6.43l-1.94,6.87l-1.2,3.86l6.47,4.69L130.12,178.05zM264.36,205.36l0.32,-1.01l-0.03,-3.17l-2.19,-2.08l-2.57,1.05l-1.19,4.17l0.7,3.56l3.14,-0.36L264.36,205.36zM288.18,212.9l4.41,6.6l3.45,2.85l4.92,-7.87l0.87,-4.93l-4.41,-0.47l-4.03,-6.7l-4.45,-1.64l-6.6,-4.97l5.15,-3.63l-2.65,-7.54l-2.44,-3.35l-6.77,-3.35l-2.92,-5.55l-5.21,1.99l-0.36,-3.86l-3.86,-4.32l-6.22,-4.71l-2.65,3.71l-5.55,2.66l0.42,-6.06l-4.81,-10.05l-7.11,4.06l-2.59,7.7l-2.21,-5.92l2.06,-6.37l-7.24,2.65l-2.88,3.99l-2.15,8.42l0.89,9.05l3.98,0.04l-2.93,3.92l2.33,2.96l4.55,1.25l5.93,2.42l10.2,1.82l5.08,-1.04l1.5,-2.42l2.21,2.79l2.47,0.46l2.97,4.96l-1.8,1.98l5.68,2.63l4.29,3.68l1.08,2.55l0.77,3.24l-3.63,6.93l-0.98,3.44l0.94,2.42l-5.77,0.86l-5.27,0.12l-1.85,4.87l2.37,2.23l8.11,-1.03l-0.04,-1.89l4.08,3.15l4.18,3.28l-0.98,1.77l3.4,3.02l6.02,3.53l7.6,2.39l-0.46,-2.09l-2.92,-3.67l-3.96,-5.37l7.03,5l3.54,1.66l0.97,-4.44l-1.82,-6.3l-1.16,-1.73l-3.81,-3.03l-2.95,-3.91l0.35,-3.94L288.18,212.9zM222.35,51.34l2.34,7.29l4.96,5.88l9.81,-1.09l6.31,1.97l-4.38,6.05l-2.21,-1.78l-7.66,-0.71l1.19,8.31l3.96,6.04l-0.8,5.2l-4.97,3.46l-2.27,5.47l4.55,2.65l3.82,8.55l-7.5,-5.7l-1.71,0.94l1.38,9.38l-5.18,2.83l0.35,5.85l5.3,0.63l4.17,1.44l8.24,-1.84l7.33,3.27l7.49,-7.19l-0.06,-3.02l-4.79,0.48l-0.39,-2.84l3.92,-3.83l1.33,-5.15l4.33,-3.83l2.66,-4.76l-2.32,-7.1l1.94,-2.65l-3.86,-1.89l8.49,-1.63l1.79,-3.15l5.78,-2.6l4.8,-13.47l4.57,-4.94l6.62,-11.12l-6.1,0.1l2.54,-4.3l6.78,-3.99l6.84,-8.9l0.12,-5.73l-5.13,-6.04l-6.02,-2.93l-7.49,-1.82l-6.07,-1.49l-6.07,-1.5l-8.1,3.98l-1.49,-2.53l-8.57,0.98l-5.03,2.57l-3.7,3.65l-2.13,11.74L239,24.52l-3.48,-1.14l-4.12,7.97l-5.5,3.35l-3.27,0.66l-4.17,3.84l0.61,6.65L222.35,51.34zM296.75,316.34l-0.98,-1.98l-1.06,1.26l0.7,1.36l3.56,1.71l1.04,-0.26l1.38,-1.66l-2.6,0.11L296.75,316.34zM239.75,238.48l0.61,1.63l1.98,0.14l3.28,-3.34l0.06,-1.19l-3.85,-0.06L239.75,238.48zM301.88,304.92l-2.87,-1.8l-3.69,-1.09l-0.97,0.37l2.61,2.04l3.63,1.34l1.36,-0.08L301.88,304.92zM326.76,309.71l-0.36,-2.24l-1.96,0.72l0.87,-3.11l-2.8,-1.32l-1.29,1.05l-2.49,-1.18l0.98,-1.51l-1.88,-0.93l-1.83,1.47l1.86,-3.82l1.5,-2.8l0.54,-1.22l-1.3,-0.2l-2.43,1.55l-1.74,2.53l-2.9,6.92l-2.35,2.56l1.22,1.14l-1.75,1.47l0.43,1.23l5.44,0.13l3.01,-0.25l2.69,1.01l-1.98,1.93l1.67,0.14l3.25,-3.58l0.78,0.53l-0.61,3.37l1.84,0.77l1.27,-0.15l1.18,-3.61L326.76,309.71zM305.57,314.47l-2.81,4.56l-4.63,0.58l-3.64,-2.01l-0.92,-3.07l-0.89,-4.46l2.65,-2.83l-2.48,-2.09l-4.19,0.43l-5.88,3.53l-4.5,5.45l-2.38,0.67l3.23,-3.8l4.04,-5.57l3.57,-1.9l2.35,-3.11l2.9,-0.3l4.21,0.03l6,0.92l4.74,-0.71l3.53,-3.62l4.62,-1.59l2.01,-1.58l2.04,-1.71l-0.2,-5.19l-1.13,-1.77l-2.18,-0.63l-1.11,-4.05l-1.8,-1.55l-4.47,-1.26l-2.52,-2.82l-3.73,-2.83l1.13,-3.2l-3.1,-6.26l-3.65,-6.89l-2.18,-4.98l-1.86,2.61l-2.68,6.05l-4.06,2.97l-2.03,-3.16l-2.56,-0.85l-0.93,-6.99l0.08,-4.8l-5,-0.44l-0.85,-2.27l-3.45,-3.44l-2.61,-2.04l-2.32,1.58l-2.88,-0.58l-4.81,-1.65l-1.95,1.4l0.94,9.18l1.22,5.12l-3.31,5.75l3.41,4.02l1.9,4.44l0.23,3.42l-1.55,3.5l-3.18,3.46l-4.49,2.28l1.98,2.53l1.46,7.4l-1.52,4.68l-2.16,1.46l-4.17,-4.28l-2.03,-5.17l-0.87,-4.76l0.46,-4.19l-3.05,-0.47l-4.63,-0.28l-2.97,-2.08l-3.51,-1.37l-2.01,-2.38l-2.8,-1.94l-5.21,-2.23l-3.92,1.02l-1.31,-3.95l-1.26,-4.99l-4.12,-0.9l0.15,-6.41l1.09,-4.48l3.04,-6.6l3.43,-4.9l3.26,-0.77l0.19,-4.05l2.21,-2.68l4.01,-0.42l3.25,-4.39l0.82,-2.9l2.7,-5.73l0.84,-3.5l2.9,2.11l3.9,-1.08l5.49,-4.96l0.36,-3.54l-1.98,-3.98l2.09,-4.06l-0.17,-3.87l-3.76,-3.95l-4.14,-1.19l-3.98,-0.62l-0.15,8.71l-2.04,6.56l-2.93,5.3l-2.71,-4.95l0.84,-5.61l-3.35,-5.02l-3.75,6.09l0.01,-7.99l-5.21,-1.63l2.49,-4.01l-3.81,-9.59l-2.84,-3.91l-3.7,-1.44l-3.32,6.43l-0.22,9.34l3.27,3.29l3,4.91l-1.27,7.71l-2.26,-0.2l-1.78,5.88l0.02,-7l-4.34,-2.58l-2.49,1.33l0.32,4.67l-4.09,-0.18l-4.35,1.17l-4.95,-3.35l-3.13,0.6l-2.82,-4.11l-2.26,-1.84l-2.24,0.77l-3.41,0.35l-1.81,2.61l2.86,3.19l-3.05,3.72l-2.99,-4.42l-2.39,1.3l-7.57,0.87l-5.07,-1.59l3.94,-3.74l-3.78,-3.9l-2.75,0.5l-3.86,-1.32l-6.56,-2.89l-4.29,-3.37l-3.4,-0.47l-1.06,2.36l-3.44,1.31l-0.38,-6.15l-3.73,5.5l-4.74,-7.32l-1.94,-0.89l-0.63,3.91l-2.09,1.9l-1.93,-3.39l-4.59,2.05l-4.2,3.55l-4.17,-0.98l-3.4,2.5l-2.46,3.28l-2.92,-0.72l-4.41,-3.8l-5.23,-1.94l-0.02,27.65l-0.01,35.43l2.76,0.17l2.73,1.56l1.96,2.44l2.49,3.6l2.73,-3.05l2.81,-1.79l1.49,2.85l1.89,2.23l2.57,2.42l1.75,3.79l2.87,5.88l4.77,3.2l0.08,3.12l-1.56,2.35l0.06,2.48l3.39,3.45l0.49,3.76l3.59,1.96l-0.4,2.79l1.56,3.96l5.08,1.82l2,1.89l5.43,4.23l0.38,0.01h7.96h8.32h2.76h8.55h8.27h8.41l8.42,0l9.53,0l9.59,0l5.8,0l0.01,-1.64l0.95,-0.02l0.5,2.35l0.87,0.72l1.96,0.26l2.86,0.67l2.72,1.3l2.27,-0.55l3.45,1.09l1.14,-1.66l1.59,-0.66l0.62,-1.03l0.63,-0.55l2.61,0.86l1.93,0.1l0.67,0.57l0.94,2.38l3.15,0.63l-0.49,1.18l1.11,1.21l-0.48,1.56l1.18,0.51l-0.59,1.37l0.75,0.13l0.53,-0.6l0.55,0.9l2.1,0.5l2.13,0.04l2.27,0.41l2.51,0.78l0.91,1.26l1.82,3.04l-0.9,1.3l-2.28,-0.54l-1.42,-2.44l0.36,2.49l-1.34,2.17l0.15,1.84l-0.23,1.07l-1.81,1.27l-1.32,2.09l-0.62,1.32l1.54,0.24l2.08,-1.2l1.23,-1.06l0.83,-0.17l1.54,0.38l0.75,-0.59l1.37,-0.48l2.44,-0.47v0l0,0l-0.25,-1.15l-0.13,0.04l-0.86,0.2l-1.12,-0.36l0.84,-1.32l0.85,-0.46l1.98,-0.56l2.37,-0.53l1.24,0.73l0.78,-0.85l0.89,-0.54l0.6,0.29l0.03,0.06l2.87,-2.73l1.27,-0.73l4.26,-0.03l5.17,0l0.28,-0.98l0.9,-0.2l1.19,-0.62l1,-1.82l0.86,-3.15l2.14,-3.1l0.93,1.08l1.88,-0.7l1.25,1.19l0,5.52l1.83,2.25l3.12,-0.48l4.49,-0.13l-4.87,3.26l0.11,3.29l2.13,0.28l3.13,-2.79l2.78,-1.58l6.21,-2.35l3.47,-2.62l-1.81,-1.46L305.57,314.47zM251.91,243.37l1.1,-3.12l-0.71,-1.23l-1.15,-0.13l-1.08,1.8l-0.13,0.41l0.74,1.77L251.91,243.37zM109.25,279.8L109.25,279.8l1.56,-2.35L109.25,279.8zM105.85,283.09l-2.69,0.38l-1.32,-0.62l-0.17,1.52l0.52,2.07l1.42,1.46l1.04,2.13l1.69,2.1l1.12,0.01l-2.44,-3.7L105.85,283.09z">
 <animate id="dash" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="25s" fill="freeze" values="3635;0"/> 
<animate id="fillCanada" attributeName="fill" values="white;#AFCD72" begin="dash.end-17s" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
</path> 

</svg>
```

Comment: @И что не понравилось минусующему? Хоть вышел бы из тени и сказал, что не устраивает. Я может дополню ответ. Такие вопросы встречались мне, значит востребовано решение.

Answer (score 6):

*Добавлено несколько карт.*

### Карта России

Анимация появления названия государства и столицы реализовано  по другому принципу в сравнении с картой Казахстана.
Использовано свойство SVG `scale` при увеличении параметров которого, масштабируемый предмет движется из угла к центру.

```
<text x="75" y="200" font-size="24" font-family="serif" font-weight="600" dx="70" dy="20" transform="scale(0 0)" fill="#AFCD72" textLength="200" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs"> Россия 
<animateTransform id="animScale" attributeName="transform" type="scale" values="0 0;1 1" begin="fillRus.end" dur="0.3s" fill="freeze" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0 0.25 0.25 1"/>
    <animate id="animFill" attributeName="fill" from="#AFCD72" to="grey" begin="fillRus.end" dur="0.3s" fill="freeze"/>
</text>
```

*Ниже полный код анимации*

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500"  >
<path id="RU" title="Russia" transform="translate(-525 -10)"  stroke-dasharray="2835" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-width="1" stroke="grey" fill="none" class="land"  d="M1008.27,215.75l-2.78,2.97l-4.6,0.7l-0.07,6.46l-1.12,1.35l-2.63,-0.19l-2.14,-2.26l-3.73,-1.92l-0.63,-2.89l-2.85,-1.1l-3.19,0.87l-1.52,-2.37l0.61,-2.55l-3.36,1.64l1.26,3.19l-1.59,2.83l-0.02,0.04l-3.6,2.89l-3.63,-0.48l2.53,3.44l1.67,5.2l1.29,1.67l0.33,2.53l-0.72,1.6l-5.23,-1.32l-7.84,4.51l-2.49,0.69l-4.29,4.1l-4.07,3.5l-1.03,2.55l-4.01,-3.9l-7.31,4.42l-1.28,-2.08l-2.7,2.39l-3.75,-0.76l-0.9,3.63l-3.36,5.22l0.1,2.14l3.19,1.17l-0.38,7.46l-2.6,0.19l-1.2,4.15l1.17,2.1l-4.9,2.47l-0.97,5.4l-4.18,1.14l-0.84,4.66l-4.04,4.18l-1.04,-3.08l-1.2,-6.69l-1.56,-10.65l1.35,-6.95l2.37,-3.07l0.15,-2.44l4.36,-1.18l5.01,-6.78l4.83,-5.73l5.04,-4.57l2.25,-8.37l-3.41,0.51l-1.68,4.92l-7.11,6.36l-2.3,-7.14l-7.24,2l-7.02,9.56l2.32,3.38l-6.26,1.42l-4.33,0.56l0.2,-3.95l-4.36,-0.84l-3.47,2.7l-8.57,-0.94l-9.22,1.62l-9.08,10.33l-10.75,11.78l4.42,0.61l1.38,3l2.72,1.05l1.79,-2.38l3.08,0.31l4.05,5.19l0.09,3.92l-2.19,4.51l-0.24,5.27l-1.26,6.85l-4.23,6.01l-0.94,2.82l-3.81,4.66l-3.78,4.53l-1.81,2.28l-3.74,2.25l-1.77,0.05l-1.76,-1.86l-3.76,2.79l-0.44,1.26l-0.39,-0.66l-0.02,-1.93l1.43,-0.1l0.4,-4.55l-0.74,-3.36l2.41,-1.4l3.4,0.7l1.89,-3.89l0.96,-4.46l1.09,-1.51l1.47,-3.76l-4.63,1.24l-2.43,1.65l-4.26,0l-1.13,-3.95l-3.32,-3.03l-4.88,-1.38l-1.04,-4.28l-0.98,-2.73l-1.05,-1.94l-1.73,-4.61l-2.46,-1.71l-4.2,-1.39l-3.72,0.13l-3.48,0.84l-2.32,2.31l1.54,1.1l0.04,2.52l-1.56,1.45l-2.53,4.72l0.03,1.93l-3.95,2.74l-3.37,-1.63l-3.35,0.36l-1.47,-1.46l-1.68,-0.47l-4.11,3.06l-3.69,0.71l-2.58,1.06l-3.53,-0.7l-2.6,0.04l-1.7,-2.2l-2.75,-2.09l-2.81,-0.58l-3.55,0.57l-2.65,0.81l-3.98,-1.84l-0.53,-3.32l-3.3,-1.15l-2.54,-0.53l-3.14,-1.87l-2.9,4.66l1.14,2.6l-2.73,3.03l-4.05,-1.09l-2.8,-0.16l-1.87,-2.04l-2.92,-0.06l-2.44,-1.35l-4.26,2.07l-5.35,3.74l-2.96,0.74l-1.1,0.35l-1.49,-2.63l-3.61,0.58l-1.19,-1.84l-1.96,-0.85l-1.35,-2.55l-1.55,-0.8l-4.03,1.14l-3.86,-2.57l-1.49,2.33l-6.27,-11.58l-3.58,-3.66l1.03,-1.5l-7.03,4.49l-2.69,0.27l0.23,-2.58l-3.6,-1.63l-2.93,1.17l-0.88,-5.01l-5.04,-1.06l-2.52,2.03l-7.02,1.79l-1.37,1.19l-10.49,1.66l-1.29,1.62l2.02,3.21l-2.69,1.2l0.53,1.25l-2.69,2.22l4.54,3.1l-0.7,2.11l-3.94,-0.19l-0.81,1.31l-3.59,-2.29l-4.45,0.09l-2.98,1.87l-3.32,-1.79l-6.18,-3.1l-4.38,0.12l-5.79,4.85l-0.35,3.19l-2.88,-2.53l-2.24,4.77l0.82,0.87l-1.62,3.21l2.38,2.84l2.08,-0.12l1.79,2.76l-0.28,2.1l1.42,0.66l-1.28,2.39l-2.72,0.66l-2.79,4.09l2.55,3.7l-0.28,2.59l3.06,4.46l-1.67,1.51l-0.48,0.95l-1.24,-0.25l-1.93,-2.27l-0.79,-0.13l-1.76,-0.87l-0.86,-1.55l-2.62,-0.79l-1.7,0.6l-0.49,-0.71l-3.82,-1.83l-4.13,-0.62l-2.37,-0.66l-0.34,0.45l-3.57,-3.27l-3.2,-1.48l-2.42,-2.32l2.04,-0.64l2.33,-3.35l-1.57,-1.6l4.13,-1.67l-0.07,-0.9l-2.52,0.66l0.09,-1.83l1.45,-1.16l2.71,-0.31l0.44,-1.4l-0.62,-2.33l1.14,-2.23l-0.03,-1.26l-4.13,-1.41l-1.64,0.05l-1.73,-2.04l-2.15,0.69l-3.56,-1.54l0.06,-0.87l-1,-1.93l-2.24,-0.22l-0.23,-1.39l0.7,-0.91l-1.79,-2.58l-2.91,0.44l-0.85,-0.23l-0.71,1.04l-1.05,-0.18l-0.69,-2.94l-0.66,-1.54l0.54,-0.44l2.26,0.16l1.09,-1.02l-0.81,-1.25l-1.89,-0.83l0.17,-0.86l-1.14,-0.87l-1.76,-3.15l0.6,-1.31l-0.27,-2.31l-2.74,-1.18l-1.47,0.59l-0.4,-1.24l-2.95,-1.26l-0.9,-2.99l-0.24,-2.49l-1.35,-1.19l1.2,-1.66l-0.83,-4.96l2,-3.13l-0.42,-0.96l3.19,-3.07l-2.94,-2.68l6,-7.41l2.6,-3.45l1.05,-3.1l-4.15,-4.26l1.15,-4.15l-2.52,-4.85l1.89,-5.76l-3.26,-7.96l2.59,-5.48l-4.29,-4.99l0.41,-5.4l2.26,-0.72l4.77,-3.19l2.89,-2.81l4.61,4.86l7.68,1.88l10.59,8.65l2.15,3.51l0.19,4.8l-3.11,3.69l-4.58,1.85l-12.52,-5.31l-2.06,0.9l4.57,5.1l0.18,3.15l0.18,6.75l3.61,1.97l2.19,1.66l0.36,-3.11l-1.69,-2.8l1.78,-2.51l6.78,4.1l2.36,-1.59l-1.89,-4.88l6.53,-6.74l2.59,0.4l2.62,2.43l1.63,-4.81l-2.34,-4.28l1.37,-4.41l-2.06,-4.69l7.84,2.44l1.6,4.18l-3.55,0.91l0.02,4.04l2.21,2.44l4.33,-1.54l0.69,-4.61l5.86,-3.52l9.79,-6.54l2.11,0.38l-2.76,4.64l3.48,0.78l2.01,-2.58l5.25,-0.21l4.16,-3.19l3.2,4.62l3.19,-5.09l-2.94,-4.58l1.46,-2.66l8.28,2.44l3.88,2.49l10.16,8.8l1.88,-3.97l-2.85,-4.11l-0.08,-1.68l-3.38,-0.78l0.92,-3.83l-1.5,-6.49l-0.08,-2.74l5.17,-7.99l1.84,-8.42l2.08,-1.88l7.42,2.51l0.58,5.18l-2.66,7.28l1.74,2.78l0.9,5.94l-0.64,11.07l3.09,4.73l-1.2,5.01l-5.49,10.2l3.21,1.02l1.12,-2.51l3.08,-1.82l0.74,-3.55l2.43,-3.49l-1.63,-4.26l1.31,-5.08l-3.07,-0.64l-0.67,-4.42l2.24,-8.28l-3.64,-7.03l5.02,-6.04l-0.65,-6.62l1.4,-0.22l1.47,5.19l-1.11,8.67l3,1.59l-1.28,-6.37l4.69,-3.58l5.82,-0.49l5.18,5.18l-2.49,-7.62l-0.28,-10.28l4.88,-2.02l6.74,0.44l6.08,-1.32l-2.28,-5.38l3.25,-7.02l3.22,-0.3l5.45,-5.51l7.4,-1.51l0.94,-3.15l7.36,-1.08l2.29,2.61l6.29,-6.24l5.15,0.2l0.77,-5.24l2.68,-5.33l6.62,-5.31l4.81,4.21l-3.82,3.13l6.35,1.92l0.76,6.03l2.56,-2.94l8.2,0.16l6.32,5.84l2.25,4.35l-0.7,5.85l-3.1,3.24l-7.37,5.92l-2.11,3.08l3.48,1.43l4.15,2.55l2.52,-1.91l1.43,6.39l1.23,-2.56l4.48,-1.57l9,1.65l0.68,4.58l11.72,1.43l0.16,-7.47l5.95,1.74l4.48,-0.05l4.53,5.14l1.29,6.04l-1.66,3.84l3.52,6.98l4.41,3.49l2.71,-9.18l4.5,4l4.78,-2.38l5.43,2.72l2.07,-2.47l4.59,1.24l-2.02,-8.4l3.7,-4.07l25.32,6.06l2.39,5.35l7.34,6.65l11.32,-1.62l5.58,1.41l2.33,3.5l-0.34,6.02l3.45,2.29l3.75,-1.64l4.97,-0.21l5.29,1.57l5.31,-0.89l4.88,6.99l3.47,-2.48l-2.27,-5.07l1.25,-3.62l8.95,2.29l5.83,-0.49l8.06,3.84l3.92,3.44l6.87,5.86l7.35,7.34l-0.24,4.44l1.89,1.74l-0.65,-5.15l7.61,1.07L1008.27,215.75zM880.84,306.25l-2.82,-7.68l-1.16,-4.51l0.07,-4.5l-0.97,-4.5l-0.73,-3.15l-1.25,0.67l1.11,2.21l-2.59,2.17l-0.25,6.3l1.64,4.41l-0.12,5.85l-0.65,3.24l0.32,4.54l-0.31,4.01l0.52,3.4l1.84,-3.13l2.13,2.44l0.08,-2.84l-2.73,-4.23l1.72,-6.11L880.84,306.25zM537.82,278.77l-2.94,-0.86l-3.87,1.58l-0.64,2.13l3.45,0.55l5.16,-0.07l-0.22,-1.23l0.3,-1.33L537.82,278.77zM979.95,178.65l3.66,-0.52l2.89,-2.06l0.24,-1.19l-4.06,-2.51l-2.38,-0.02l-0.36,0.37l-3.57,3.64l0.5,2.73L979.95,178.65zM870.07,151.56l-2.66,3.92l0.49,0.52l5.75,1.08l4.25,-0.07l-0.34,-2.57l-3.98,-3.81L870.07,151.56zM894.64,142.03l3.24,-4.25l-7.04,-2.88l-5.23,-1.68l-0.67,3.59l5.21,4.27L894.64,142.03zM869.51,140.34l10.33,0.3l2.21,-8.14l-10.13,-6.07l-7.4,-0.51l-3.7,2.18l-1.51,7.75l5.55,7.01L869.51,140.34zM622.39,166.28l-2.87,1.96l0.41,4.83l5.08,2.35l0.74,3.82l9.16,1.1l1.66,-0.74l-5.36,-7.11l-0.57,-7.52l4.39,-9.14l4.18,-9.82l8.71,-10.17l8.56,-5.34l9.93,-5.74l1.88,-3.71l-1.95,-4.83l-5.46,1.6l-4.8,4.49l-9.33,2.22l-9.26,7.41l-6.27,5.85l0.76,4.87l-6.71,9.03l2.58,1.22l-5.56,8.27L622.39,166.28zM769.87,98.34l0.83,-5.72l-7.11,-8.34l-2.11,-0.98l-2.3,1.7l-5.12,18.6L769.87,98.34zM605.64,69.03l3.04,3.88l3.28,-2.69l0.39,-2.72l2.52,-1.27l3.76,-2.23l1.08,-2.62l-4.16,-3.85l-2.64,2.9l-1.61,4.12l-0.57,-4.65l-4.26,0.21L601,63.25l6.24,0.52L605.64,69.03zM736.89,82.07l4.65,5.73l7.81,4.2l6.12,-1.8l0.69,-13.62l-6.46,-16.04l-5.45,-9.02l-6.07,4.11l-7.28,11.83l3.83,3.27L736.89,82.07z"> 
   <animate id="dash" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="10s" fill="freeze" values="2835;0"/>  

<animate id="fillRus" attributeName="fill" values="white;#AFCD72" begin="dash.end-2s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
</path>  

<text x="75" y="200" font-size="24" font-family="serif" font-weight="600" dx="70" dy="20" transform="scale(0 0)" fill="#AFCD72" textLength="200" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs"> Россия 
<animateTransform id="animScale" attributeName="transform" type="scale" values="0 0;1 1" begin="fillRus.end" dur="0.3s" fill="freeze" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0 0.25 0.25 1"/>
    <animate id="animFill" attributeName="fill" from="#AFCD72" to="grey" begin="fillRus.end" dur="0.3s" fill="freeze"/>
</text>  

<text fill="purple" x="-100" y="245" font-size="12" dx="0" textLength="50" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs">
    Москва <tspan dx="-33" dy="19" font-size="22" fill="teal">&#9992;</tspan>
    <animate attributeName="x" from="-100" to="47" begin="animFill.end" dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0 0.25 0.25 1"/>
  </text>

</svg>
```

### Карта Казахстана

Усложнена анимация на примере карты Казахстана,- добавлена цепочка последовательных анимаций.

- По окончании анимации прорисовки контуров карты и заполнения её
  цветом начинается анимация текста - названия государства.

  `<text x="40" y="50"  font-size="12"  fill="none" stroke="none" >Казахстан 
       <animate id="fillKaz" dur="1.5s" begin="fillPath.end"  repeatCount="1"
          attributeName="fill"   values="#AFCD72;#787A78" fill="freeze" />
   </text>`
- Затем начинается цепочка последовательных анимаций:   прорисовки
  знака столицы

  `<g  opacity="0">
      <circle cx="68" cy="35" r="2" fill="#787A78" stroke="none"  />
      <circle cx="68" cy="35" r="0.8" fill="#787A78" stroke="white" stroke-
           width="0.5" />
      <animate id="fillCircle" attributeName="opacity" values="0;1" 
           begin="fillKaz.end" dur="0.8s" fill="freeze" />
      </g>`
- названия столицы государства:

  `<text x="70" y="32" font-size="5"  fill="none" stroke="none"> Астана 
    <animate id="fillAstana" dur="1.5s" begin="fillCircle.end"  repeatCount="1"
          attributeName="fill"   values="#AFCD72;#787A78" fill="freeze" />
   </text>`
  **Ниже полый код анимации:**

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 120 120"  >
<path id="KZ" title="Kazakhstan" class="land" transform="translate(-603 -260)" fill="none" stroke="grey" stroke-width="0.2" stroke-dasharray="395" stroke-dashoffset="395" d="M674.22,333.11L672.61,333.81L668.92,336.42L667.69,339.07L666.64,339.09L665.88,337.34L662.31,337.22L661.74,334.16L660.37,334.13L660.58,330.33L657.23,327.53L652.42,327.83L649.13,328.39L646.45,324.89L644.16,323.41L639.81,320.57L639.29,320.22L632.07,322.57L632.18,336.7L630.74,336.88L628.78,333.95L626.88,332.89L623.7,333.68L622.46,334.93L622.3,334.01L622.99,332.44L622.46,331.12L619.21,329.82L617.94,326.35L616.4,325.37L616.3,324.09L619.03,324.46L619.14,321.58L621.52,320.94L623.97,321.53L624.48,317.62L623.98,315.11L621.17,315.31L618.79,314.31L615.54,316.1L612.93,316.96L611.5,316.3L611.79,314.2L610,311.44L607.92,311.55L605.54,308.72L607.16,305.5L606.34,304.63L608.57,299.86L611.46,302.39L611.81,299.2L617.59,294.35L621.97,294.23L628.16,297.33L631.47,299.12L634.45,297.25L638.89,297.17L642.48,299.46L643.3,298.15L647.23,298.34L647.94,296.23L643.39,293.14L646.08,290.91L645.56,289.66L648.25,288.45L646.23,285.25L647.51,283.63L658,281.97L659.37,280.78L666.39,278.99L668.91,276.95L673.95,278.01L674.83,283.02L677.76,281.86L681.36,283.49L681.13,286.07L683.82,285.8L690.84,281.31L689.82,282.81L693.4,286.47L699.66,298.05L701.16,295.72L705.02,298.28L709.05,297.14L710.59,297.94L711.94,300.49L713.9,301.33L715.1,303.18L718.71,302.6L720.2,305.23L718.06,308.06L715.73,308.46L715.6,312.64L714.04,314.5L708.48,313.15L706.46,320.41L705.02,321.3L699.47,322.88L701.99,329.63L700.07,330.63L700.29,332.79L698.56,332.24L697.16,330.87L693,330.47L688.35,330.37L687.33,330.79L683.33,329.18L681.74,329.98L681.31,332.22L676.69,330.91L674.85,331.45z">
 <animate id="dash" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="4s" fill="freeze" values="395;0"/> 
<animate id="fillPath" attributeName="fill" values="white;#AFCD72" begin="dash.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
</path>  

<text x="40" y="50"  font-size="12"  fill="none" stroke="none" >Казахстан 
     <animate id="fillKaz" dur="1.5s" begin="fillPath.end"  repeatCount="1"
        attributeName="fill"   values="#AFCD72;#787A78" fill="freeze" />
 </text>

<g  opacity="0">
<circle cx="68" cy="35" r="2" fill="#787A78" stroke="none"  />
<circle cx="68" cy="35" r="0.8" fill="#787A78" stroke="white" stroke-width="0.5" />
<animate id="fillCircle" attributeName="opacity" values="0;1" begin="fillKaz.end" dur="0.8s" fill="freeze" />
</g>
 
 <text x="70" y="32" font-size="5"  fill="none" stroke="none"   >Астана 
  <animate id="fillAstana" dur="1.5s" begin="fillCircle.end"  repeatCount="1"
        attributeName="fill"   values="#AFCD72;#787A78" fill="freeze" />
 </text>

</svg>
```

### Карта Белоруссии

```html
<svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 50 50" >
<path id="BY" class="land"  title="Belarus" transform="translate(-530 -265)" fill="none" stroke="grey" stroke-width="0.1" stroke-dasharray="91" stroke-dashoffset="91" d="M541.1,284.07L543.81,284.11L546.85,282.31L547.5,279.59L549.8,278.02L549.54,275.82L551.24,274.98L554.26,273.05L557.21,274.31L557.61,275.54L559.08,274.95L561.82,276.13L562.09,278.44L561.49,279.76L563.25,282.91L564.39,283.78L564.22,284.64L566.11,285.47L566.92,286.72L565.83,287.74L563.57,287.58L563.03,288.02L563.69,289.56L564.38,292.49L561.97,292.76L561.11,293.76L560.92,296.02L559.81,295.59L557.28,295.81L556.54,294.76L555.49,295.54L554.44,294.89L552.23,294.8L549.1,293.72L546.27,293.36L544.1,293.46L542.56,294.69L541.22,294.86L541.17,292.85L540.3,290.73L541.98,289.79L542,287.94L541.22,286.16z">
 <animate id="dash" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="5s" fill="freeze" values="91;0"/> 
<animate id="fillCanada" attributeName="fill" values="white;#AFCD72" begin="dash.end" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
</path> 

</svg>
```

### Карта Грузии

```html
<svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 20 20" >
<path id="GE" class="land"  title="Georgia" transform="translate(-587 -325)" fill="none" stroke="grey" stroke-width="0.05" stroke-dasharray="49" stroke-dashoffset="49" d="M591.76,335.85L592.18,334.25L591.48,331.68L589.86,330.27L588.31,329.83L587.28,328.66L587.62,328.2L589.99,328.86L594.12,329.48L597.94,331.31L598.43,332.02L600.13,331.42L602.75,332.22L603.6,333.77L605.37,334.64L604.64,335.15L606.02,337.17L605.64,337.6L604.13,337.38L602.04,336.32L601.35,336.92L597.45,337.5L594.75,335.68z">
 <animate id="dash" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="5s" fill="freeze" values="49;0"/> 
<animate id="fillCanada" attributeName="fill" values="white;#AFCD72" begin="dash.end" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
</path> 

</svg>
```

### Карта Армении

```html
<svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 20 20" >
<path id="AM" title="Armenia" class="land" transform="translate(-591 -335)" fill="none" stroke="grey" stroke-width="0.04" stroke-dasharray="30" stroke-dashoffset="30" d="M597.45,337.5L601.35,336.92L601.93,337.9L603,338.54L602.43,339.46L603.93,340.72L603.14,341.88L604.33,342.87L605.59,343.46L605.65,345.96L604.63,346.06L603.49,343.98L603.5,343.43L602.26,343.44L601.43,342.46L600.85,342.56L599.74,341.5L597.66,340.59L597.93,338.8z">
 <animate id="dash" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="5s" fill="freeze" values="30;0"/> 
<animate id="fillCanada" attributeName="fill" values="white;#AFCD72" begin="dash.end" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
</path> 

</svg>
```

Comment: Отлично шапка сидит)

Comment: @HamSter комментарию год, и он снова стал актуальным :))))

Comment: Вам эта шапка идет, сэр! )))